# object has no hasOwnProperty method (i.e. it's undefined) - IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools, hasownproperty

This seems quite bizarre.

Here's my experiment in the IE8 console:

```
typeof obj1 // "object"
obj1.hasOwnProperty // {...}

typeof obj2 // "object"
obj2.hasOwnProperty // undefined
```

Any ideas as to what could cause this?

Comment: is obj2 a host object? Are you in IE7/ IE8 / quirks mode ?

Comment: regarding `difference between native objects and host objects?`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript

Comment: A workaround that doesn't need the use of hasOwnProperty(): [hasOwnProperty() is undefined on the window object in IE8 and causes a TypeError](http://sixdayprogrammer.com/2014/10/138/)

Comment: I had this problem as I wanted to know if there is  a property  exists in object or not so , I can solve by this Link  : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/check-if-object-property-exists-using-a-variable

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This example is from IE8, but the same return is from IE6+ and most other IE browsers.

IE before #9 does not define it for **host** objects

```
var o=window;// or document or document elements
o.hasOwnProperty

/*  returned value: (undefined)
undefined
*/
```

Comment: Maybe `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window,name)`?

Comment: @panzi: Thank you so much! This works in IE8, and now incompatible browsers are properly detected my my site. (before, would crash on blank page, since no window.hasOwnProperty)

Comment: @panzi: It would be probably better if you post the information from comment as the answer. It's really *the solution* of the problem.

Comment: @Oleg It was only guessed (hence the "maybe"). Does it actually work? Then I'll write an answer.

Comment: @panzi: As I know all DOM elements/nodes created in IE8 have the same problem with `hasOwnProperty`, but one can successfully use  `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(domElement,name)`.