# How to check if object property exists with a variable holding the property name?

Tags: javascript, object, typeguards

I am checking for the existence of an object property with a variable holding the property name in question.

```
var myObj;
myObj.prop = "exists";
var myProp = "p"+"r"+"o"+"p";

if(myObj.myProp){
    alert("yes, i have that property");
};
```

This is `undefined` because it's looking for `myObj.myProp` but I want it to check for `myObj.prop`

Comment: Possibly useful: From a comment by Pablo Cabrera at [NCZOnline](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/27/determining-if-an-object-property-exists/): "I think it’s worth to note that if the `hasOwnProperty` method is overwritten, you can rely on the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property)`."

Comment: is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable a duplicate of this question? how is that? 'checking existence' and 'accessing value' are different things? Please correct me if I am wrong ....

Comment: this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @HumanInDisguise comments should not be used to provide resolving advice.  Your comment would have been better placed as an answer which contains static quoted advice and a link to its source.  Now that @ adnan2d has posted this advice, your comment can be safely deleted.

Answer (score 1557, accepted):

```
var myProp = 'prop';
if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(myProp)){
    alert("yes, i have that property");
}
```

Or

```
var myProp = 'prop';
if(myProp in myObj){
    alert("yes, i have that property");
}
```

Or

```
if('prop' in myObj){
    alert("yes, i have that property");
}
```

Note that `hasOwnProperty` doesn't check for inherited properties, whereas `in` does.  For example `'constructor' in myObj` is true, but `myObj.hasOwnProperty('constructor')` is not.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty()` is better then `myObj[myProp]` (from other answers) as it works even if the value of `myProp` is 0

Comment: The "in" operator does not work with strings. e.g. 'length' in 'qqq' will produce an exception. So if you want a general purpose check you need to use hasOwnProperty.

Comment: @Jacob what do you mean when you say 'The "in" operator does not work with strings'? with "in"' operator the left expression must be a string or value that can converts into a string. Yes, you cannot write 'length' in 'qqq' but you cannot write 'qqq'.hasOwnProperty('length') either

Comment: @Wachburn: `'qqq'.hasOwnProperty('length')` is `true`, you can do that.

Comment: @MattR what do you mean by "it works even if the value of myProp is 0" ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 I believe what I am referring to is that if `myProp` is 0, the if statement would look like `if (myObj[0])` which if `myObj` has any properties at all, the expresssion would evaluate to `true`. And `myObj[0]` may not be the property you are looking for.

Comment: To avoid breaking eslint `no-prototype-builtins` rule you should use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, myProp)` instead of `myObj.hasOwnProperty(myProp)`

Comment: @RocketHazmat while you *can* indeed do 'qqq'.hasOwn... that does not check if the object qqq has anything. It checks that the anonymous string with value "qqq" has that property, which seems useless since you know at compile time if that is true or not so why would you check that at runtime? I mean you're technically correct but... not sure it holds as an argument against using `in` unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: @AnorZaken I think it refers to when you pass a variable whose value is a string. For example `var s = 'foo'; if ('prop' in s) {} /* vs */ if (s.hasOwnProperty('prop')) {}`, the first will throw an error but the second will check correctly.

Answer (score 61):

You can use **hasOwnProperty**, but based on the reference you need **quotes** when using this method:

```
if (myObj.hasOwnProperty('myProp')) {
    // do something
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Another way is to use **in** operator, but you need **quotes** here as well:

```
if ('myProp' in myObj) {
    // do something
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: That is [**not**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8eegdry/1) how `hasOwnProperty()` is implemented.

Comment: This is incorrect. By putting quotes around the name myProp, you are no longer referencing the value of myProp, rather you are declaring a new String() of 'myProp' and there is no such property of 'myProp' in myObj.

Comment: TriumpST: from MDN linked above, "prop - A string or symbol representing a property name or array index (non-symbols will be coerced to strings)."

Comment: This is correct. If you don't want to use a variable, but just if a specific 'myProp' is present, you need the quotes.

Comment: @KatinkaHesselink: Your comment is misleading. The question was "How to check if object property exists with a variable holding the property name?"

Comment: just used in in Chrome 80 with double quotes, worked for me. :/

Comment: 'hasOwnProperty' is not equivalent to using the 'in' operator, as Rocket Hazmat's answer explains.

Answer (score 27):

Thank you for everyone's assistance and pushing to get rid of the eval statement. 
Variables needed to be in brackets, not dot notation. This works and is clean, proper code.

Each of these are variables: appChoice, underI, underObstr.

```
if(typeof tData.tonicdata[appChoice][underI][underObstr] !== "undefined"){
    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: This looks like a problem to me. If `tData.tonicdata[appChoice]` results in a value that doesn't have a property/index that matches `underI`, then this will result in an `TypeError` being thrown.

Comment: Despite your intentions with your initial post, you actually asked a different question than the one for which you provided this answer. You wanted to check the existence of a property, you don't mention anything about how to access it. Which makes this answer unrelated to the actual question.

Answer (score 24):

For own property :

```
var loan = { amount: 150 };
if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(loan, "amount")) 
{ 
   //will execute
}
```

Note: using **Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty** is better than loan.hasOwnProperty(..), in case a custom hasOwnProperty is defined in the prototype chain (which is not the case here), like

```
var foo = {
      hasOwnProperty: function() {
        return false;
      },
      bar: 'Here be dragons'
    };
```

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

To include inherited properties in the finding use the **in** operator: (but you must place an object at the right side of 'in', primitive values will throw error, e.g.  **'length' in 'home'** will throw error, but **'length' in new String('home')** won't)

```
const yoshi = { skulk: true };
const hattori = { sneak: true };
const kuma = { creep: true };
if ("skulk" in yoshi) 
    console.log("Yoshi can skulk");

if (!("sneak" in yoshi)) 
    console.log("Yoshi cannot sneak");

if (!("creep" in yoshi)) 
    console.log("Yoshi cannot creep");

Object.setPrototypeOf(yoshi, hattori);

if ("sneak" in yoshi)
    console.log("Yoshi can now sneak");
if (!("creep" in hattori))
    console.log("Hattori cannot creep");

Object.setPrototypeOf(hattori, kuma);

if ("creep" in hattori)
    console.log("Hattori can now creep");
if ("creep" in yoshi)
    console.log("Yoshi can also creep");
```

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Note: One may be tempted to use typeof and [ ] property accessor as the following code which **doesn't work always** ...

```
var loan = { amount: 150 };

loan.installment = undefined;

if("installment" in loan) // correct
{
    // will execute
}

if(typeof loan["installment"] !== "undefined") // incorrect
{
    // will not execute
}
```

Answer (score 13):

A much more secure way to check if property exists on the object is to use empty object or object prototype to call `hasOwnProperty()`

```
var foo = {
  hasOwnProperty: function() {
    return false;
  },
  bar: 'Here be dragons'
};

foo.hasOwnProperty('bar'); // always returns false

// Use another Object's hasOwnProperty and call it with 'this' set to foo
({}).hasOwnProperty.call(foo, 'bar'); // true

// It's also possible to use the hasOwnProperty property from the Object
// prototype for this purpose
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, 'bar'); // true
```

Reference from [MDN Web Docs - Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: If you are incorporating JavaScript that might do something evil like override `hasOwnProperty`, no amount of guards like this will make your code safe or secure.

Comment: @meustrus I know where you coming from, but from business perspective it is highly possible to receive that an inexperienced developer would use this property name, which not necessarily mean their are doing something evil intentionally.

Answer (score 12):

there are much simpler solutions and I don't see any answer to your actual question:

> "it's looking for myObj.myProp but I want it to check for myObj.prop"

1. to obtain a property value from a variable, use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).
2. to test that property for truthy values, use [optional
   chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
3. to return a boolean, use [double-not / bang-bang / (!!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!)
4. use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) if you are certain you have an object and only want to check for the existence of the property (`true` even if prop value is undefined).  or perhaps combine with [nullish coalescing operator ??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to avoid errors being thrown.

```js
var nothing = undefined;
var obj = {prop:"hello world"}
var myProp = "prop";

consolelog( 1,()=> obj.myProp); // obj does not have a "myProp"
consolelog( 2,()=> obj[myProp]); // brackets works
consolelog( 3,()=> nothing[myProp]); // throws if not an object
consolelog( 4,()=> obj?.[myProp]); // optional chaining very nice ⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️
consolelog( 5,()=> nothing?.[myProp]); // optional chaining avoids throwing
consolelog( 6,()=> nothing?.[nothing]); // even here it is error-safe
consolelog( 7,()=> !!obj?.[myProp]); // double-not yields true
consolelog( 8,()=> !!nothing?.[myProp]); // false because undefined
consolelog( 9,()=> myProp in obj); // in operator works
consolelog(10,()=> myProp in nothing); // throws if not an object
consolelog(11,()=> myProp in (nothing ?? {})); // safe from throwing
consolelog(12,()=> myProp in {prop:undefined}); // true (prop key exists even though its value undefined)

// beware of 'hasOwnProperty' pitfalls
// it can't detect inherited properties and 'hasOwnProperty' is itself inherited
// also comparatively verbose
consolelog(13,()=> obj.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty")); // DANGER: it yields false 
consolelog(14,()=> nothing.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty")); // throws when undefined
obj.hasOwnProperty = ()=>true; // someone could overwrite it
consolelog(15,()=> obj.hasOwnProperty(nothing)); // DANGER: the foolish overwrite will now always return true
consolelog(16,()=> Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj,"hasOwnProperty")); // explain?!
consolelog(17,()=> Object.hasOwn(obj,"hasOwnProperty")); // explain?!

function consolelog(num,myTest){
    try{
    console.log(num,myTest());
    }
    catch(e){
    console.log(num,'throws',e.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `hasOwnProperty()` as well as `in` operator.

Comment: All of this ^ is why I hate javascript

Comment: @pwaterz don't hate the [player](https://giphy.com/search/javascript) 

Comment: 'hasOwnProperty' is not equivalent to using the 'in' operator, as Rocket Hazmat's answer explains.

Comment: maybe you could try to explain when does using either option don't really matters, but accepted answer is pretty clear

Answer (score 5):

Using the new `Object.hasOwn` method is another alternative and it's intention is to replace the `Object.hasOwnProperty` method.

This static method returns true if the specified object has the indicated property as its own property or false if the property is inherited or does not exist on that object.

Please not that you must check the Browser compatibility table carefully before using this in production since it's still considered an  experimental technology and is not fully supported yet by all browsers (soon to be though)

```js
var myObj = {};
myObj.myProp = "exists";

if (Object.hasOwn(myObj, 'myProp')) {
  alert("yes, i have that property");
}
```

More about `Object.hasOwn` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn

`Object.hasOwn` browser compatibility - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to check if an object property exists.

```
const dog = { name: "Spot" }

if (dog.name) console.log("Yay 1"); // Prints.
if (dog.sex) console.log("Yay 2"); // Doesn't print. 

if ("name" in dog) console.log("Yay 3"); // Prints.
if ("sex" in dog) console.log("Yay 4"); // Doesn't print.

if (dog.hasOwnProperty("name")) console.log("Yay 5"); // Prints.
if (dog.hasOwnProperty("sex")) console.log("Yay 6"); // Doesn't print, but prints undefined.
```

Answer (score 1):

Working for me.

```
if (typeof receviedData?.d?.heartbeat_interval != "undefined") {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the answers I didn't see the `!!` truthiness check.

```
if (!!myObj.myProp) //Do something
```

Comment: Can you please link me to some documentation on this `!!` operator? I have searched google high and low and I cannot find it anywhere, I can only find the `!` operator

Comment: This is just a double negation pattern. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose

Comment: You didn’t see it here because it’s wrong. This is not a property-existence check, but a truthiness check.