# ClojureScript to check if a property exists in a js object

Tags: clojurescript

How do I write the following in clojurescript?

```
obj = {"a" : 4};
"a" in obj;
```

Comment: did you see https://himera.herokuapp.com/synonym.html ?

Comment: This works too: `(js* "'a' in obj")`. But thats cheating ;)

Comment: usage of js* is a bad practice, try to not use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the accepted SO way to check if a js object property exists using the method "[hasOwnProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/check-if-object-property-exists-using-a-variable)" We can translate it as follows:

```
(def foo (js-obj "bar" "baz"))
(.hasOwnProperty foo "bar")
;; => true
(.-bar foo)
;;=> "baz"
(.hasOwnProperty foo "car")
=> false
(.-car foo)
;;=> nil
```

Answer (score 11):

exists? was [added](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-495) to check for `undefined` in ClojureScript :

```
   (ns my.ns
     (:require-macros [cljs.core :refer [exists?]]))

   (if (exists? js/jQuery)
      (println "jQuery"))
      (println "no jQuery"))
```

One can also use `aget` and `nil?` to avoid calling JavaScript functions :

```
(def scope (js-obj))
(aset scope "var1" "Value")
(aget scope "var1")               ;; "Value"
(aget scope "anotherVar")         ;; nil
(nil? (aget scope "anotherVar"))  ;; true
```