# Inherited property check

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to tell whether an inherited object property was set to be undefined or doesn't exist at all?

I have a formatting string with a property name in it, and an object that's expected to contain the property. I don't care if the property is the object's own or inherited, I need to know if it exists at all so I can use it, even if it was set as undefined, but if it doesn't exist at all, I need to throw an error.

I know just how many times this subject has been danced around, and with so many opinions about using:

```
if(prop in obj){
}
```

and this one:

```
obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)
```

And while I clearly cannot use the second one, the first method seems unreliable when it comes to all possible property values.

Is there a reliable way to check if a particular property exists either within object or inherited, even if its value was set to 0 or null or undefined?

Comment: *The first method seems unreliable when it comes to all possible property values.* What makes you think so? `var foo = { bar: undefined }; "bar" in foo => true`

Comment: Many comments in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/check-if-object-property-exists-using-a-variable

Comment: The only relevant and correct comment that I could find is the one that says `in` does not work with strings. Are you sure that's a concern in your use case?

Comment: Well, my property name is a string variable, so perhaps yes, if that's what they meant in the comment.

Comment: `var o = {s: "foo"}; 's' in o => true`

Comment: @vitaly, their comment says that `var foo = "foo"; "length" in foo => Exception`

Comment: The only reason I can think of why `in` by itself might not be sufficient is if you don't want it to return true for properties that belong to the base `Object.prototype`. In that case you can just check `(prop in obj && !(prop in Object.prototype))`

Comment: ..with regard to the comment @FrédéricHamidi mentioned, that's because string literals are sort of quasi-objects. If you explicitly made a String object then it would work: `var foo = new String("foo"); "length" in foo` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `if(prop in obj)` seems unreliable when it comes to all possible property values.

No. The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) does not care about the values at all, it checks only for the property name. It's exactly what you want.

Comment: Following all the comments to my question, I find this answer being pretty convincing. Thank you!