# Some properties are missing from API's returned data, need solid way to check property

Tags: javascript

I'm aware that api team is the one responsible for sending correct data to the client that requested the data. However, I still would like to know the best way of checking if property exists or not.

```
// when state property is missing from the api response
myObject = {
  name : 'Scott',
  addressInfo : {
    address1 : '444 St Peter St',
    address2 : 'Apartment D',
    zipCode  : '55555'
  },
  birthDate : '20000101'
}
```

or

```
// or when birtdate is missing
myObject = {
  name : 'Scott',
  addressInfo : {
    address1 : '444 St Peter St',
    address2 : 'Apartment D',
    zipCode  : '55555',
    state    : 'MN'
  }
}
```

or

```
// when addressInfo is missing
myObject = {
  name : 'Scott',
  birthDate : '20000101'
}
```

Is the code below enough for the checking?

```
if (myObject.addressInfo !== undefined && myObject.addressInfo.state !== undefined) {

    // console.log(
}
```

Comment: `if (myObject.addressInfo) ...` returns a boolean, so if it's not on the object it returns false; no need to do a further check for `myObject.addressInfo.state` if the parent doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), then a very convenient way to test if a key is present in an object is the `_.has` method:

```
var x = { "a": 1 };
_.has(x,"a"); //returns true
_.has(x,"b"); //returns false
```

Comment: using _.has(), how will you check state property? Like this? _.has(myObject, 'addressInfo.state')

Comment: Like this : `_.has(myObject.addressInfo, 'state')`. In your case myObject.addressInfo is the object being inspected, and 'state' is the key that you are checking.

Answer (score 1):

`state` value could be set as `undefined` though still be a property of `myObject` ; try utilizing `Object.hasOwnProperty(property)`

```js
var myObject = {
  name : 'Scott',
  addressInfo : {
    address1 : '444 St Peter St',
    address2 : 'Apartment D',
    zipCode  : '55555'
  },
  birthDate : '20000101'
};

console.log(myObject.addressInfo.hasOwnProperty("state"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way to check proerty exists:

```
if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(myProp)){
    alert("yes, i have that property");
}
```

and

```
if(myProp in myObj){
    alert("yes, i have that property");
}
```

From answer:
[check if object property exists - using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/check-if-object-property-exists-using-a-variable)