# js check if obj is available

Tags: javascript, php

So, I have following js :

```
var NAMES = {

'185' : {
        'FIRST'     : 'first',
        'MIDDLE'    : 'middle',
        'LAST'      : 'last'
    }
};

for (var j = 0; j < (id.length); j++) {         
     var uDATA_ID = id[j]; //string
     var uDATA_OBJ = JSON.parse(uDATA_ID);  //converted to object            
     if (uDATA_ID == NAMES.uDATA_OBJ){
        alert("Somethings happening");                               
     }
}
```

So, I get a string of `id`s from php.  I need to check if this number is available in the object variable.

However, I am having a hard time making it work.

Could someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: `uDATA_ID == NAMES.uDATA_OBJ` doesn't make much sense to me. What is supposed to do?

Comment: Sp. `uDATA_ID` has a value of "185". I am trying to see if the top array contains the same value.

Comment: Duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/218196) and [check if object property exists - using a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11040472/218196)

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable to access an object field, use the `[field]` syntax instead of the `.field` syntax:

```
 var data = NAMES[uDATA_ID]
```

If that field is missing, it will return `undefined` (which you can then check for)

```
 if (data) {   // assumes you don't want `false` or `0`.
```

Comment: Thanks. That was bit frustrating as some of the old answered from SO had different syntax format. Thanks for the clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick question. How would I check if the "top" array contains the same object? (For example, `if (typeof uDATA_ID == NAMES[uDATA_OBJ])`)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects