# Javascript in check vs dot notation check

Tags: javascript, variables, object

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040508/3645944) I know I can check if a property exists using the in operator. So I see in a lot of code that it is common to use, for example:

```
if ("gapi" in window) {
    gapi.login(...);
}
```

But wouldn't be better to do it this way?

```
if (window.gapi) {
    gapi.login(...);
}
```

The only difference that I am aware of is that the second one will return false if the variable exists but its value is `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `null` or other value that evaluates to false; and the first one will return true, right?

So, is there any other difference? Which one should I use?

Comment: With the latter, what if `window.gapi` were 0, false, null, etc?

Comment: @Marty yes, that is what I stated in my last paragraph before the question

Comment: Your last paragraph strictly mentions `undefined` from what I understand.

Comment: @Marty you are right, I had those values in mind but didnt write all of them. I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Your question is unusual now as it reads something like "what are the differences between these two things excluding this significant list of differences?".

Comment: @Marty yes but my point is that is really common to use the first one but I think that because of that difference, the second one should be better. Then I think that maybe there are other differences that make the first one "better"

Comment: As you've hinted in your responses to the answers below, it depends entirely on the use case. It's unlikely that you would want to attempt to "login" with something other than a valid string with length greater than zero, but in another instance you might be happy to accept `null` as a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there's a significant difference. What if `gapi` is falsy (`0`, `false`, empty string, `null`)? That will skip over the block.

Comment: Yes, but this depends on what I want. Because if its undefined. I don't want to execute `gapi.login` because it will fail, right?

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez `undefined` is falsey

Comment: Yes! Thats what I am saying, in the first block, if it is undefined it will enter the block and execute something that will fail because `login` is not a property of undefined

Answer (score 2):

Use the first one. With the second, it will return false if window.gapi happens to be 0, false, '', null, undefined, etc. This means that even if window.gapi exists, your code may not think it does.

Comment: Yes, but this depends on what I want. Because if its undefined. I don't want to execute `gapi.login` because it will fail, right?