# valid object property in javascript

Tags: javascript-objects

how can i check if any javaScript object's property exists and if it exists then it has a valid value?
actually,i am a beginner and trying to solve this-

> Check if the second argument is truthy on all objects of the first argument(which is an array of objects).i.e.

- check if the second argument exists in all the objects in first argument(an array) as a property.
  if it exists, it should not be-
- invalid, as age can't be 0
- null
- undefined
- empty string('')
- NaN

till now i have this-

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {

  for(var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
    if(!(pre in collection[i])||collection[i]     

      [pre]===undefined||isNaN(collection[i]      

      [pre])||collection[i][pre]===""||           

      collection[i][pre]===null||collection[i]    

      [pre]===0)
       {
          return false;
       } 
   }
 return true;
}
```

i know this is not the best wayto solve .Is there a better way to do this?i don't like that long if statement in my code.i have seen other  SO links-[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/check-if-object-property-exists-using-a-variable),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript) but none of them seemed to solve my query. any kind of help is highly appreciated.
P.S. this code is not working for some true cases even.

Comment: I think you're looking for pre.hasOwnProperty(collection[i])

Comment: @MatthewCarpenter no, it's the other way round. i have used this also- collection[i].hasOwnProperty(pre) but that worked the same way.didn't made any difference.

Comment: @MatthewCarpenter i found out the solution. you can see my answer posted below! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
o = new Object();
o.prop = 'exist';

if(o.hasOwnProperty('prop')){
   if(o['prop']){
     alert('good value')
   }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6003920/1074179

Comment: no,this is not working .this is just working for checking the if key exists or not.P.S i want concise code. :)

Comment: hasOwnProperty('prop') checks if the property exist and then o['prop'] checks for empty strings (""), null, undefined, false and the numbers 0 and NaN

Comment: sorry,i can't mark this as best answer due to less reputations. you should also see my answer. something new that i found i.e.using Boolean() function.

Comment: @srishtisharma now you have enough rep)

Answer (score 1):

this is what i was looking for and absolutely logical-

```
for(var i in array){  
  if((prop in array[i])&& Boolean(array[i][prop]))  
  {  
  //do something  
  }   
}
```

the Boolean() function is something which made my day. Learn more at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below example.

let the json object be

```
 var a = { obj1:"a",obj2:"b"}
```

to check if an object exists,you can use hasOwnProperty() method.

```
a.hasOwnProperty("obj2") //this will return true
a.hasOwnProperty("obj3") // this will return false
```

to check the value of an object

```
 if(a["obj1"] && a["obj1"]!="" && a["obj"]!=0){
  //place your logic here
}
```

Comment: i have tried using that (hasOwnProperty()) but that didn't worked also.both worked the same way.

Comment: can you please post the json object? so that i can give a try.

Comment: ya sure, here -truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female"}], "sex"); this should return true.

Comment: below code works fine for me,
var a=[{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex":"female"}]
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      { 
           var flag= true;
            if(!a[i]["sex"]){
                flag = false;
            }
}

Comment: try this-truthCheck([{"single": "double"}, {"single": NaN}], "single");  P.S. the key may exist or not and all the "should not be present" is not responding correctly in this case.i have tried this earlier.

Comment: Yeah it is working fine. [link](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c9c1b7a) view my console output in the above link

Comment: yes,it works! that was a silly mistake earlier and it works all fine with hasOwnProperty(). :)

Comment: thanks and please see my answer also which is using Boolean() function. :)