# javascript - checking for a property on a nested object with 'property' in object fails

Tags: javascript

I have the following object called `this.props`:

```
{
  children: null,
  location: {
    action: 'POP',
    query: {
      seconds: '300'
    }
  }
}
```

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/check-if-object-property-exists-using-a-variable) I wrote the following code:

```
let seconds = 0;

console.log(this.props);

if('seconds' in this.props) {
 seconds = parseInt(this.props.location.query.seconds, 10);
}

console.log(seconds);
```

In the console the object is logged as above, but `seconds` is logged as 0.

I do not understand what is wrong with my if check, it seems that the condition is failing even though the nested object has the correct property (the issue is that when there is no query object, the whole this.props object is empty - so I need to check for nested properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seconds is not in this.props; it's on  query. The `in` operator is not recursive, just first level:

```
if('seconds' in this.props.location.query) {
 seconds = parseInt(this.props.location.query.seconds, 10);
}

console.log(seconds); // 300
```

If you want to do it recursively, create your own function:

```
let isIn = function (obj, key) {
  return isObj(obj) ? (key in obj) || Object.values(obj).filter(f => isIn(f, key)).length > 0 : false;
}
```

Where `isObj` is a function that verifies if the parameter is an object. You can use lodash or equiv., or make something like:

```
let isObj = t => (t !== null) && (typeof t === 'object');
```

Comment: so what would be the proper way to check for nested objects, if there is any? My problem is that if I do not get any parameters in my URL then this.props is just an empty object - {}

Comment: I added an example :)