# (js) how to simultaneously iterate through an object while iterating through values

Tags: javascript

[image]

I am basically trying to get this problem to work and have isolated the issue to line 21. I think the way I'm trying to access the object key is wrong. I am simply trying to say: if the object key in the new object exists in the original array, push the new value from the new object into the new array.

#### Edit to add code block

```
function valueReplace(array, obj) {
  var replaced = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    var value = obj[array[i]];

    if (array.indexOf(obj.i) !== -1) {
      replaced.push(value);
    } else {
      replaced.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return replaced;
}
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste the code into the question itself please? Images are really bad way to communicate text & code.

Comment: @felix-kling, embedding the image into the question makes the code even less readable

Comment: What you want is to check whether a property exists. This is explained here: [How to check if object property exists with a variable holding the property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11040472/218196)

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko: More incentive to replace is with the actual source code then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mixed up error report, but at the actual code, you try to access the object with the property `i`, `obj.i`, which not exists. Read more about [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

For getting the wanted result, you might use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for checking if a property in an object exists.

```
if (array[i] in obj) {
     replaced.push(obj[array[i]]);
} else {
    replaced.push(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the issues you are having is trying to access a dynamic property with dot notation, which JS generally doesn't like. I reversed your logical if because IMO it makes more sense to see if the object has a property than get a property and then get the index of the array, but you could reverse it back to using index of by `array.indexOf(obj[i]) !== -1`

```
function valueReplace(array, obj) {
  let replaced = [];

  for (let i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(array[i])) {
      replaced.push(obj[array[i]]);
    } else {
      replaced.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return replaced;
}
```

Because I generally like simplifying things here is this functionality rewritten in ES6 compatible code, using [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Don't use it for your homework, but if you want you can work it backwards into a standard function ;).

```
const valueReplace = (array, obj) => array.map(val => (obj.hasOwnProperty(val)) ? obj[val] : val);
```