# Check if the property exist in array

Tags: javascript

The name `attribute_name:"position"` is very rare and I want to check that if the property exists I want to push it to the new array. However, every time I try to add a condition it gives me errors.

`[0].attribute_name` inside the `for` loop is giving me trouble. There may or may not be two arrays inside `activity_attributes`. But I want to make a call bases on first array, if the `itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0].attribute_name` push them to new array.

[image: attribute_name position]

```
if(res.status == "success") {
    var itemloop = res.response.activities;
    var social_post_link = [];
    for(var i=0; i<itemloop.length; i++){
        if(itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0].attribute_name == "position") {
            social_post_link.push(itemloop[i].activity_attributes);
        }
    }
    console.log(social_post_link);
}
```

Comment: why you dont use filter instead  and push the required value?

Comment: can you show me how to do that please?

Comment: can you put your array into a code instead of a pictur ?

Comment: You are directly trying to check using attribute_name that's why giving error in case property not exist. You can check whether property exist or not by referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/how-to-check-if-object-property-exists-with-a-variable-holding-the-property-name thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if('attribute_name' in yourObject)` to achieve that.

**Demo.**

```js
var res = {
  status: 'success',
  response: {
    activities : [
      {
        activity_attributes: [
          {
            attribute_name: 'position'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        activity_attributes: [
          {
            test: 'test'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};


if(res.status == "success") {
    var itemloop = res.response.activities;
    var social_post_link = [];
    for(var i=0; i<itemloop.length; i++){
      if( 'attribute_name' in itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0]){ //HERE
        if(itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0].attribute_name == "position") {
            social_post_link.push(itemloop[i].activity_attributes);
        }
      }
        
    }
    console.log(social_post_link);
}
```

Comment: `if( 'attribute_name' in itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0])` this is giving me error because there are some array those doesn't have even `activity_attributes' array

Comment: Then also check `if('activity_attribute' in itemloop[i])`

Comment: Thanks your logic worked. I did a little modification `if(itemloop[i].activity_attributes) ` and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Use should use the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method

```
if(itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0].hasOwnProperty('attribute_name') && itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0].attribute_name == "position")
```

You code should be like

```
if(res.status == "success") {
    var itemloop = res.response.activities;
    var social_post_link = [];
    for(var i=0; i<itemloop.length; i++){
        if(itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0].hasOwnProperty('attribute_name') && itemloop[i].activity_attributes[0].attribute_name == "position") {
            social_post_link.push(itemloop[i].activity_attributes);
        }
    }
    console.log(social_post_link);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and `Array.prototype.map()` can be combined to construct new `arrays` based on `predicated rules` such as `attribute_name == 'position'` and `return` child `values`.

See below for a practical example.

```
if (res.status == 'success') {
  const itemloop = res.response.activities
  const social_post_link = itemloop.filter(x => x.attribute_name == 'position').map(x => x.activity_attributes)
  console.log(social_post_link)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `activity_attributes[0].attribute_name` ,try using `activity_attributes[0]['attribute_name'] == 'position'`