# How to verify is set variable in object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

How to verify is set variable in object?

```html
        <script> 
        var json;
      //json = {"one":1,"two":0}
        console.log(typeof json.one); 
        console.log("How to verify is set json?"); 
        </script>
```

Comment: `json && typeof json === 'object' && json.hasOwnProperty('one')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if object property exists with a variable holding the property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/how-to-check-if-object-property-exists-with-a-variable-holding-the-property-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your question is if a object has certain property or not the below way works

```
var json = {"one":1,"two":0};
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(json) === "[object Object]" && json.hasOwnProperty('one')){
  console.log('json contains one property');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (json && json.one) {
   console.log("It's set!");
}
```

Comment: What about `TypeError: json is undefined`

Comment: True but the question is: How to verify is set variable in object? But let me edit my answer for you.

Comment: If(typeof json.one == 'undefined")

Answer (score 0):

If(typeof json.one == 'undefined")