# How to dynamically check if a property exists in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

By dynamically I mean that this prop won't be the same depending where I am checking it from.
For example, I have this hook:

```js
export const useErrorBorder = (fieldName: string) => {
  const { formState: { errors } } = useFormContext()
  const colors = { clean: 'blue.500', error: 'red.500' }

  let showErrorBorder = colors.clean

  if (errors && Object.keys(errors)?.length && fieldName) {
    showErrorBorder = colors.error
  } else {
    showErrorBorder = colors.clean
  }

  if (!fieldName) {
    showErrorBorder = 'inherit'
  }

  return showErrorBorder
}
```

Where I need to check if `fieldName` exists in the `errors` object of the `formState` from `useFormContext` hook.

So when I call this hook, I use like this:

```js
  const handleErrorHook = useErrorBorder(
    Object.keys(errors)?.length ? errors?.logic[conditionIndex]?.skipQuestionsSelect : '',
  )
```

Or depending if I call it on another component:

```js
  const handleErrorHook = useErrorBorder(
    Object.keys(errors)?.length ? errors?.logic[conditionIndex]?.scenarios[scenarioIndex]?.operator : ''
  )
```

```js
<Comp focusBorderColor={handleErrorHook?.showErrorBorder || 'inherit'}` />
```

As you noticed `skipQuestionsSelect` is not inside the `scenarios` array. And, when `skipQuestionsSelect` or `operator` are empty they will be remove from their positions

So I am getting errors like these:
[image]

So what will be the best solution to avoid this error?

Comment: Why don’t you use `Object.keys(obj).includes('key')`?

Comment: Your error is referencing code that you didn't (fully) include in your question? Also, even though a screenshot looks nice, (also) include your error in a code block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if object property exists with a variable holding the property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/how-to-check-if-object-property-exists-with-a-variable-holding-the-property-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) your `errors?.logic[conditionIndex]?.scenarios[scenarioIndex]?.operator` bit.

If you want to optional chain with a `[key]` access, use `?.[key]`, e.g. `errors?.logic?.[conditionIndex]?.scenarios?.[scenarioIndex]?.operator`.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript there are two ways to access object properties, that are dot notation: `something.bar` or  with bracket notation: `something['bar']`
With the bracket notation you can access the object properties dynamically passing the string value of the key inside the bracket.

So in your case that you have the key stored on a variable so you simply put the variable with the key name inside the brackets like this:

```js
var objectKey = 'someKey';
var objectWithSomeKey = {
  someKey: 'Hello'
};

console.log(objectWithSomeKey[objectKey]);
```