# Different types of components in same ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting an object from an API. It has an array which contains 2 types of objects, I have to loop over this array and render two different components depending on the object at each index.

Both types of components need `@Input`s and `@Output`s to work properly, so I can't use `<ng-container>` like showing in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040508/3251645).

What's the best way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 components, then you could use something like this to check which component type to render:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="<type check condition here> ? type1 : type2; context: { $implicit: item }">
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<!-- in each one of these templates you can access the item in the array via "item" -->
<ng-template #type1 let-item>
  <!-- render component for type 1 here -->
</ng-template>

<ng-template #type2 let-item>
  <!-- render component for type 2 here -->
</ng-template>
```

You might want to look into [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) as well if the number of component types increases in the future.