# optional chaining and logical assignment JS

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a property exists in my object or not, If it exists I want to add a number to it and if it doesn't I want to create a property and set the value to 1.
I did everything and i used optional chaining and logical assignment but there is an error it says:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
can you say whats the problem?
here is the code:

```
const scores = {};
for (const player of Object.values(game.scored)) {
  scores?.[player]++ && scores[player] = 1;
}
```

note: game.scored contains 4 names;

i did my best, i could do it with ternary operator and it worked but i want to know why it doesn't work with optional chaining and logical assignment

Comment: Well first, using `&&` like that will evaluate _both_ conditions, so if this works at all and a score already exists, it would increment the score and then set it to `1` — you'd want to use `||` so if the left side increments the _or_ condition is satisfied and the right side won't be evaluated.

Comment: You're probably after [optional **assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) not optional chaining: `scores[player] ??= 0; scores[player] += 1;`

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't tack on tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to an optionally chained expression; they can't appear on the "left-hand side" of an assignment.

This would require something like this to work:

```
a?.foo = 1
```

How is this supposed to work when `a` is null? You'd effectively be producing the statement `undefined = 1`.

In your case you're expecting this to work:

```
 scores?.[player] = scores?.[player] + 1
```

What happens if `scores` is `null`? You end up with `undefined = undefined + 1`, neither the left-hand or right-hand side of that assignment make sense.

---

Note that, the whole thing is written incorrectly, and it makes no sense to write `scores?.[player]` when you've *just* assigned `scores = {}` two lines up. `scores?.[player]` checks whether `scores` is null, not whether `scores[player]` is null.

You're trying to test whether the key `player` is already in the object `scores`, which is here: [How to check if object property exists with a variable holding the property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040472/how-to-check-if-object-property-exists-with-a-variable-holding-the-property-name)

Comment: thank you but i have another question how does this work?
  scores[player] ? scores[player]++ : (scores[player] = 1);
now scores[player] is undefiend and i set it to 1
in other code I add 1 to the value but if it's undefiend js will run the right side and in the right side I set it to 1 like this one.
but if it's not undefiend it just add 1 to it.

Comment: @parsa_keshavarzi I don't really follow your question. `scores[player] ? scores[player]++ : scores[player] = 1` works just fine. As written, it's no different from the equivalent `if`/`else` which should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

```
  scores[player] = (scores[player] ?? 0) + 1;
```

here, (scores[player] ?? 0) checks if the left expression is null, and if so it returns the one on the right, otherwise it'll return the one on the left. Therefore scores[player] will be assigned scores[player] + 1 when it already exists, and be created and assigned a 1 when it doesn't. HIH