# Difference between Object.method(o) and o.method()

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it Object.defineProperty() rather than this.defineProperty() (for objects)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239317/why-is-it-object-defineproperty-rather-than-this-defineproperty-for-objects)

I noticed that all the methods of a particular object can be called from the actual object instance, i.e., `object.method();` or by passing the object to `Object.method()` as an argument. For example:

```
var a = ['one', 2, 3, 'four'];
a.reverse();
// OR
Array.reverse(a);
```

I seemed to get the same behaviour. I was wondering what the difference was and when one would be used over the other?

Comment: related: [Why is it Object.defineProperty() rather than this.defineProperty() (for objects)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239317/why-is-it-object-defineproperty-rather-than-this-defineproperty-for-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object.method(o)` looks on the `Object` object (`Object` is a real object in JavaScript) for a property called `method` and tries to call it passing in the variable `o`. During the call, `this` will be `Object`.

`o.method()` looks on the object referenced by the variable `o` for a property called `method` and tries to call it, not passing anything in. During the call, `this` will be `o`.

As you can see, they do quite different things.

> I noticed that all the methods of a particular object can be called from the actual object instance...or by passing the object to `Object.method()` as an argument.

No, they cannot. Your example `Array.reverse(a)` fails on a standard implementation of `Array` because `Array` doesn't have a property called `reverse` and so it can't be called as a function. **Edit**: You note in the comments that it works in Firefox's scratchpad, and I just verified that. That means Firefox's SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine is applying a non-standard extension to `Array` which provides a static implementation of `reverse`. That's specific to Firefox's `Array`, not general to all objects. (If you make your own `Foo`, for instance, its prototype functions don't magically get added to `Foo` as well.)

The *standard* way to make the near-equivalent to `a.reverse()` would be via the prototype, like this:

```
Array.prototype.reverse.call(a);
```

That *does* work in standard engines. So let's look at what it does:

1. It gets the `prototype` property from `Array`.
2. It gets the `reverse` property from the object it got in #1.
3. It calls the function that property referenced using the [`Function#call`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) feature of JavaScript function objects to make `this` be the argument you pass into `call` during the course of the function call.

When you create an array, the object gets an underlying prototype. That prototype is the object referenced by `Array.prototype` when the new array is created. So `a` has a `reverse` property because its underlying prototype has a `reverse` property.

Doing `a.reverse()` does this:

1. Gets the `reverse` property from the `a` object. Since (normally) `a` won't have its own property called `reverse`, standard JavaScript property lookup looks to `a`'s underlying prototype. It finds the property there and uses its value.
2. Calls that function such that `this` is `a` within the call.

As you can see, the end result is the same *provided* that the underlying prototype of `a` and `Array.prototype` still refer to the same object. (It's possible for them not to, although in the case of `Array` or any other built-in, if someone *replaced* [as opposed to *augmenting*] `Array.prototype`, that would be a Bad Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>.)

Comment: `Array.reverse(a)` works in firefox scratchpad for some reason (using `Ctrl+l` for the output).

Comment: @stariz77: Very interesting (and I've verified it at this end). That would be Firefox doing something non-standard, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @stariz77: BTW, I've verified that Firefox's `Array.reverse` and `Array.prototype.reverse` don't call each other. I proved it by first overriding `Array.prototype.reverse` and noting that `Array.reverse` still did the reversal, and then overriding `Array.reverse` and seeing that `Array.prototype.reverse` still did the reversal. I expect they each call an internal function to reverse the array. Thanks for the info about Firefox, I never knew that.