# Overriding Object.create method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

if I create an object in JavaScript like so:

```
var foo = {
create: function(){}
}
```

will that overwrite the Object.create function?

Comment: No, it won't. And no, you definitely may not do that anyway. Why are you asking?

Comment: related: [Why is it Object.defineProperty() rather than this.defineProperty()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13239317/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't.

The object that you create will have a `create` method, i.e. `foo.create`, but the `Object` object still has its own `create` function.

Note that the `Object.create` function isn't in `Object.prototype.create` i.e. it's not a method that exists in any object that is created, it only exists as a property of the `Object` function object.

Comment: It can also be accessed using the constructor of an object like `foo.constructor.create(foo)`

Comment: @jungy: That depends so much on `foo` that this shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I totally agree it shouldn't used.  I just don't want people to assume that a constructor and instance are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, because `create` is a property of `foo`.

For backward compatible `Object.create`:

```
if(!Object.create){
  Object.create = function(o){
    function F(){}; F.prototype = o;
    return new F;
  }
}
```