# Why some of the properties from the Object object are not inherited in sub-objects?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I found that 'keys' property was not inherited in my object, when testing the below code:

```
var obj = {x: 0, y:1};
console.log (Object.keys); //function

console.log (obj.keys); //undefined
```

So, my understanding is that some of the properties (in Object) are not inherited in user defined objects. Why? Are those properties only available through Object object? Is there any hack to get the properties list that are not available or inherited in user-defined objects?

Comment: related: [Why is it Object.defineProperty() rather than this.defineProperty() (for objects)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13239317/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `.prototype` object is inherited as the prototype. **Static class properties** are not.

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.bar = function () {};
Foo.baz = function () {};

var f = new Foo();
```

`f` will have inherited `bar`, but not `baz`.

Comment: And static properties are not inherited?

Comment: I thought I just said they are not. ;-)

Comment: @Devashish: By child classes, yes, by instances, no.

Comment: Seems like more interesting things are coming in my Js programming career. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Devashish Really you need to understand what `new` does. In a nutshell, it transports the `.prototype` of the constructor function (`Foo`) to the new object (`f`). Whatever else was tacked onto `Foo` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` is a static property of the `Object` variable, `obj.keys` is a property og the `obj` variable, which would inherit from `Object.prototype`. You'd find this would work:

```
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty); //function
```