# Why does `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` return a value, while `hasOwnProperty` returns `false`?

Tags: javascript

`Number` is an intrinsic function object that is a function property on the `globalThis`.

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(globalThis, 'Number')) // <descriptor>
```

Why, then, does `globalThis.hasOwnProperty(window, 'Number')` return `false`?

```js
console.log(globalThis.hasOwnProperty(window, 'Number')) // false
```

I'm sure I am missing something obvious...

Comment: [Object#hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) receives one argument.

Comment: hasOwnProperty should be called like `window.hasOwnProperty('Number')` or `globalThis.hasOwnProperty('Number')`

Comment: Doh! Oh dear....

Comment: It seems to be that your confusion comes from [the two different ways native functions/methods are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13239317/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your call to `hasOwnProperty` it's a member function not a class function. So your call should be `hasOwnPropery('Number')` and now `hasOwnPropery(window, 'Number')` because `globalThis` does not have a window property and all later arguments will be ignored.

```js
const globalThis = window;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(globalThis, 'Number'))
console.log(globalThis.hasOwnProperty('Number'))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the
>   object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to
>   inheriting it).

And the syntax is:

> obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)

So, if you want to check: Is `Number` a `window`'s property or not, you can try:

```js
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('Number')) // true
// or
console.log(globalThis.hasOwnProperty('Number')) // true
```

You don't need to provide the second parameter. Maybe you misread the way to use [getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) and `hasOwnProperty`