# Javascript not working in IE8, not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code. I apologize for it being messy. I am a novice, hence the problem.It is supposed to populate checkboxes from the querystring. It works in Chrome, Safari, Firefox. Just started testing on IE and in IE 8 it doesn't work. The clicks are registered, but the checkboxes don't populate. No errors are thrown, it seems to simply ignore it.

```
//set var for queryString - "?"
            var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);

            var parameters = queryString.split('&');

            var paramObject = new Object();

            for( var i =0; i < parameters.length; ++i){
                var equalsPos = parameters[i].indexOf('=');
                var key = decodeURIComponent(parameters[i].substring(0,equalsPos));

                var stringLength = parameters[i].length;

                var value = decodeURIComponent(parameters[i].substring(equalsPos + 1, stringLength).replace(/\+/g,' '));

                if(!paramObject[key]) {
                    //console.log('paramObject[key] =' + paramObject[key]);
                    paramObject[key] = value;
                    //console.log('paramObject[key] = value = ' + value + paramObject[key]);
                    //console.log(paramObject[key]);
                }else if(paramObject[key] instanceof Array){
                    paramObject[key].push(value);
                    //console.log(paramObject[key]);
                } else {
                    var newArray = [];
                    var existingValue = paramObject[key];
                    //console.log('existing value: '+ existingValue);
                    //console.log('value: ' + value);
                    newArray.push(existingValue);
                    newArray.push(value);
                    paramObject[key] = newArray;
                }

            } 

            //console.log(paramObject);


            for (key in paramObject) {

                $('input[name="' + key + '"]').each(function(){
                    var obj = paramObject[key];

                    for(prop in obj){

                        if(obj instanceof Array){

                            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                                //console.log(key + '=' + obj[prop]);
                                if($(this).attr('value') == obj[prop]){
                                    $(this).attr('checked','checked');                      
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                                if($(this).attr('value') == obj){
                                    $(this).attr('checked','checked');                      
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: How does it "not work"?  What does it do instead?  What happens in IE8?  Do you see any errors in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157700/object-has-no-hasownproperty-method-i-e-its-undefined-ie8) IE8 doesn't support the hasOwnProperty() method on host objects. There's a comment there with the answer you're looking for. Good luck!