# angular ie8 "Object doesn't support property or method 'hasOwnProperty'" workaround

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, hasownproperty

I'm using angular-1.2.1.js on ie8 and getting the error:

Object doesn't support property or method 'hasOwnProperty'
(inside the angular ForEach method)

```
function forEach(obj, iterator, context) {
  var key;
  if (obj) {
    if (isFunction(obj)){
      for (key in obj) {
        if (key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
        }
      }
    } else if ...
```

According to this  [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157700/object-has-no-hasownproperty-method-i-e-its-undefined-ie8), hasOwnProperty does not work in ie8 (at least not on the window object)

I'm not sure if things are acting weird because I'm using ie8 mode on windows 8 ie, but hasOwnProperty works when I use

```
var a = {b:'c'}
a.hasOwnProperty('b')  //true
```

why is ie8 throwing an error and how can I fix?
thanks

Comment: Try testing on a real IE8, a lot of dumb things happen in compatibility mode that you can't trust. Can you provide the code where you're **actually** using `forEach`?

Comment: In IE8, `hasOwnProperty` doesn't work on DOM Elements (or other "host objects", I'd presume).

Comment: Strange that Angular claims they've tested against IE8: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie But is known not to work in IE11 with IE8 compatibility mode: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4137 the solution there was: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)`

Comment: I'm not using forEach anywhere

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was a solution other than changing every instance of hasOwnProperty in the angular source to     Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj,key)

Comment: @Jedininjaster I'm not sure if I'm right about this, but what if you checked the `window` object for the `hasOwnProperty` property? If it's not there, you define it. Something like `window.hasOwnProperty = window.hasOwnProperty || function (key) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, key); };`. This would be put on the page before any other scripts. Anything after it that tries to access the `window.hasOwnProperty` method will use either the native method (if it's defined) or the custom one that does the same thing just in a different way. Does that help?

Comment: @Ian, but that won't work for things like b.hasOwnProperty(c); will it?

Comment: @Neil It depends on what `b` is. If it's a normal JavaScript data type, it should work fine. If it's `window` or other host objects, such as an `Element`, it may not have that method. So in general, the solution is to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(b, c);`

Comment: related I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157700/object-has-no-hasownproperty-method-i-e-its-undefined-ie8

Comment: One [should not be using `obj.hasOwnProperty(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572) anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to convert the guarded statement:

```
 /* Check for existence */
 if (key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
    {
    iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
    }
```

to a dispatch table:

```
 /* Map browser alias to stringified logic */
 var conditional = {"ie8": 
                    "key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(key, {})",

                    "w3c":
                    "key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)"
                   };
```

And a feature check to choose:

```
/* Ternary mapping of browser to logic */
var browser =  ("onpropertychange" in document) === true && (!!window.XDomainRequest) === true && (!!window.innerWidth) === false ? "ie8" : "w3c";

/* Evaluate valid result and pass to specified function */
if (eval(conditional[browser]) )
  {
  iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
  }
```

**References**

- [JavaScript/Operators - Wikibooks, open books for an open world](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators)
- [Thomas Bahn: BLUG 2010 - Advanced JavaScript (AdvancedJavaScript.pdf)](http://www.assono.de/blog/downloads/BLUG-2010-JavaScript-PDF/$file/AdvancedJavaScript.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error & found this edit on angular.js Github Source to resolve this issue:

```
if (obj) {
     if (isFunction(obj)){
       for (key in obj) {
//-        if (key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
//+        // This uglyness around hasOwnProperty is for IE8 to work properly (hasOwnProperty doesn't exist)
/*+*/        if (key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && (obj.hasOwnProperty && obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))) {
           iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
         }
       }
```

[image]

There is one more edit to make console.log work on IE8
https://github.com/pjparra/angular.js/commit/bcbf9409f10f5988f6946a7b0381eee5e6518989

Source:https://github.com/pjparra/angular.js/commit/8c2ed24412620d68a760cfab70e4dc27a49b9e91