# Typescript/Angular/ES6: can I finally let `hasOwnProperty()` die in for loops?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've always disliked the need to check `hasOwnProperty()` when looping over objects in javascript:

```
for ( var key in object ) {
    if ( !object.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // Now I can do whatever I needed to do
}
```

It always seems like wasted vertical space to loop through keys in an object and then have to explicitly check to make sure those keys didn't come from somewhere else.  I'm obviously familiar with *why* this was necessary in javascript, especially due to older libraries that would sometimes inject things into the prototype chain (**cough** Prototype **cough**).

However, to the best of my knowledge, angular does no such thing.  Typescript certainly wouldn't have reason to either.  I can't imagine any modern javascript framework would.  As a result, what are the possible downsides of skipping such a check in a modern Angular app (or any modern javascript app).  Am I only at risk of problems caused by my own team accidentally modifying prototypes (or accidentally importing libraries that modify prototypes), or is there more room for trouble that I'm not aware of?  In what other ways might the prototype chain bite me if I try to just do this?

```
for ( let key in object ) {
}
```

My own tests haven't revealed any problems, but I may be missing something obvious.  And yes, I'm aware of `Object.keys( object )` in mondern js/ts.  It gets the job done but I don't think it is as clean as a `for ... in`, which is what I would rather use if I can let `hasOwnProperty()` die.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` makes sure properties from say a parent that are inherited aren't counted.

Comment: I never have experienced such problems with angular since most of us dont' modify the prototypes

Comment: " I don't think it is as clean as a for ... in" `for(let key of Object.keys(object)) {}`

Comment: Yup, exactly @YuryTarabanko.  Why would I want to say `for(let key of Object.keys(object)){}` when I can just say `for(let key in object){}`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko that iterates over the indices of the array

Comment: @AndrewLi Nope It iterates over values.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Pretty sure `Object.keys` returns an array which you're trying to for-in over, which iterates over the properties of the array, 0, 1, 2, etc

Comment: @AndrewLi `for..in` - yes. `for..of` - no. Simply try my code in console.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Oh. I missed the `of`, thought you were using `in`. Nevermind, my bad.

Comment: " Why would I want to say" IMHO this add some expressiveness to your code. You could also say  `for(let value of Object.values(object))` or even `for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(object))` But again this is opinion based.

Comment: That's a good point @YuryTarabanko.  Python acts in a very similar way.  Although since the majority of the time I am iterating over the keys, its nice to have an condensed shorthand for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason to include this check when enumerating plain objects and others that you know have no enumerable inherited properties. You are right, no reasonable modern framework does this to `Object.prototype`.

The [death of `hasOwnProperty` checks](http://phrogz.net/death-to-hasownproperty) has been proclaimed since 2012 :-)

> Am I only at risk of problems caused by my own team accidentally modifying prototypes (or accidentally importing libraries that modify prototypes)?

Yes. Though the fix for such problems is not to modify prototypes (or to [make the property non-enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13296897/1048572)), not to add `hasOwnProperty` checks everywhere.

> Or is there more room for trouble that I'm not aware of?

No.

Actually, omitting the `if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key))` check might even *solve* some problems and avoid trouble. Not all objects you might want to enumerate are [guaranteed to have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39840363/1048572) a `hasOwnProperty` method, or one that [does what you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41471310/1048572). The proper way to check - in cases where it is necessary - has always been with `call`:

```
if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key))
```

(though of course there [still are edge cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43268580/1048572), but they don't depend on `object`)