# ESLint error use Object.keys instead of for..in

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the below code which works perfectly fine. But, ESLint suggest to use `Object.keys` instead of `for..in` loop. I tried to iterate the `keys`, do the search if the match found then return the object. It works with `for..in` but not with Object.keys. I tried to replace `forEach` with `filter` but didn't work for me. Any suggestions.

```
function searchObj (obj, query) {

  // Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
  for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
       return searchObj(value, query);
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string' && value.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
       return obj;
    }
  }
}

var demoData=[
  {id:1,desc:{original:'trans1'},date:'2017-07-16'},
  {id:2,desc:{original:'trans2'},date:'2017-07-12'},
  {id:3,desc:{original:'trans3'},date:'2017-07-11'},
  {id:4,desc:{original:'trans4'},date:'2017-07-15'}
];

var searchFilter = demoData.filter(function(obj){
     return searchObj(obj, 'trans1');
});
console.log(searchFilter);
```

here is the link [**JS bin**](http://jsbin.com/linokow/56/edit?js,console)

Comment: Why not just turn off that rule if you're happy with your code the way it is? They're just guidelines/someone else's personal opinion how code should be written, not something set in stone.

Comment: You could try `Object.keys(…).find` or `for (… of Object.keys(…))`, but honestly [your loop is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572). Just disable that es-lint rule!

Comment: @Andy if it is the only best way rather than using `for..in` how would we do that.

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth How do you run ESLint?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax

Comment: @Bergi  I have configured the ESLint to the project which watches the files automatically for any errors while I develop.

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth you could disable it for a line  `//eslint-disable-next-line`

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth If you have a ESLint configuration file, just put the rule to exclude there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't really use found object just the fact it is there. You could use `Array.prototype.some` to avoid looping over every key in `obj` is you have already found it matches the search query.

```js
function searchObj (obj, query) {
  return Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
       return searchObj(value, query);
    }
    
    return typeof value === 'string' && value.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
}

var demoData=[
  {id:1,desc:{original:'trans1'},date:'2017-07-16'},
  {id:2,desc:{original:'trans2'},date:'2017-07-12'},
  {id:3,desc:{original:'trans3'},date:'2017-07-11'},
  {id:4,desc:{original:'trans4'},date:'2017-07-15'}
];

var searchFilter = demoData.filter(function(obj){
     return searchObj(obj, 'trans1');
});
console.log(searchFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth No problem. BTW if you are using modern runtimes you could use `Object.values` to get an array of all values instead of `Object.keys` with further accessing the value manually.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Object.keys` with `forEach` to iterate through the keys, you are passing a function as callback, so the `return` statements are for that callback function instead of `searchObj`.

Instead of returning the result from the `forEach` callback, you can store it in an external variable (accessed inside the `forEach` by means of `closure`), assign it in the `forEach`, and then return its value. Here I create a variable called `foundObj` for that:

```js
function searchObj (obj, query) {
  var foundObj = null;

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
       foundObj = searchObj(value, query);
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string' && value.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
       foundObj = obj;
    }
  });

  return foundObj;
}

var demoData=[
  {id:1,desc:{original:'trans1'},date:'2017-07-16'},
  {id:2,desc:{original:'trans2'},date:'2017-07-12'},
  {id:3,desc:{original:'trans3'},date:'2017-07-11'},
  {id:4,desc:{original:'trans4'},date:'2017-07-15'}
];

var searchFilter = demoData.filter(function(obj){
     return searchObj(obj, 'trans1');
});
console.log(searchFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alberto