# Print the key and value from an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an Object like

```
let sample = {a:5, b:3 , c:7, d:8}
Object.entries(sample)
```

Now i will get an array of length four

```
[ [a,5], [b,3], [c,7] , [d,8] ]
```

Where the key and value will be as an array values.

Now i need to print the values as

- a holds the value 5
- b holds the value 3
- c holds the value 7
- d holds the value 8

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
let sample = {a:5, b:3, c:7, d:8};
for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(sample)) {
  // return whatever you need
  console.log(`${key} holds the value ${value}`)
}
```

I hope this will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The answer you posted is technically correct, but it will only work in the most modern among browsers.

For example, [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is not supported by ANY version of IE. Neither is [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). And the [let statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) requires at least IE11.

If you care about your code running in older browsers, consider using eg.
 [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead of Object.entries, [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of for...of and [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) instead of let.

This code will do the same thing, but also run fine in IE9 :

```js
var sample = {a:5, b:3 , c:7, d:8};
var keys = Object.keys(sample);

keys.forEach(function(key){
  console.log(key + " holds the value " + sample[key]);
});
```

And if even the above code is too modern for your taste, you can go for the following approach :

```js
var sample = {a:5, b:3 , c:7, d:8};

for (var key in sample) {
  console.log(key + " holds the value " + sample[key]);
}
```

That code should work even in IE6!

Comment: But `Object.keys` and `forEach` and string interpolation don't work in older browsers either… Why not use a simple `for (var key in sample) { console.log(key + " holds the value " + sample[key]) }` loop

Comment: @Bergi : Thanks for your corrections. I'd forgotten about the string interpolation, but fixed my code accordingly. I also added a second version based on `for...in` that should work in even IE6. The reason I didn't mention `for...in` in my initial answer, is because I've learnt to avoid it as a consequence of [**this issue**](https://blog.javascripting.com/2014/09/19/when-should-javascript-developers-use-hasownproperty/). And since we don't need to support IE<9 at my employer's, I've been using `Object.keys` + `forEach` as an alternative to `for...in` + `obj.hasOwnProperty` in all of my code.

Comment: I disagree. We *should* assume that `Object.prototype` is not extended with enumerable properties, just like we assume the native methods to do what we expect. [`obj.hasOwnProperty(…)` is wrong and should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi : I agree that `obj.hasOwnProperty` is totally unnecessary when looping over [POJOs](http://g-liu.com/blog/2015/08/object-oriented-programming-javascript-using-pojos-for-good/). That's why I haven't put it in my answer. However, if you're implementing a function or method that allows ANY object, it's better to add `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))` by default to prevent unwanted side-effects.

Comment: Still no - if you really don't know your objects and expect them to be unreasonable, you must use `if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))`

Comment: @Bergi : That would be even safer, yes. No disagreement here. Anyway, all I'm saying is that you can avoid this by using `Object.keys` and then looping over the keys... with `forEach`, a regular for-loop or otherwise.