# JS Copy from larger object only item that in the destination object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

OK, the title may be confusing, but here is what I am trying to do:
I have two objects

```
var smallObject = {
"FirstName" : "pacman",
"LastName" : "gamer",
"SSN" : "123-45-6789"
}

var largeObject = {
"FirstName" : "pacman",
"LastName" : "gamer",
"SSN" : "123-45-6789",
...
...
...
...
}
```

I want to be able to only copy (replace if different) the values in smallObject but not add any of the additional from largeObject

Comment: What have you tried? Do you get any errors?

Comment: havent tried anything, I dont know how to do it other than Object.Assign which will copy also the items in largeObejct which I dont need

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple loop:

```
for (const p in smaller)
    smaller[p] = larger[p];
```

If you were looking for any new ES6 builtin similar to `Object.assign`: no, there isn't any.

Comment: this will assign `undefined` to every property of `smaller` that doesn't exists in `larger`.

Comment: @Olian04 The `larger` object in the question has all the properties that `smaller` has. I thought it was implied by the naming that `larger` has the same properties as the other, and more? Even if not, it's trivial to fix by adding a `if (p in larger)` condition.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy ways to do this is as @Bergi said. Create a for-in loop and go through the properties of the `smallObject` and assign the value of the corresponding `largeObject` property to the `smallObject`.

```js
var smallObject = {
  "FirstName": "pacman",
  "LastName": "gamer",
  "SSN": "123-45-6789"
}

var largeObject = {
  "FirstName": "Pacman",
  "LastName": "Bright",
  "SSN": "123-45-1337",
  "av": "abca",
  "az": "doda",
  "asdW": "dawd"
}


for(var prop in smallObject) {
  if(smallObject.hasOwnProperty(prop) && largeObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    smallObject[prop] = largeObject[prop]
  }
}

console.log(smallObject)
```

Comment: [Don't use `object.hasOwnProperty(prop)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572).

Comment: It's correct that you don't have to do any `Object.hasOwnProperty` calls if you know that the `Object` you're working with is an plain object. But you will have to check if the property exists in `largeObject`.

Comment: Then do that by a simple `prop in largeObject` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `smallObject` isn't necessary a strict subset of `largeObject`.

```js
const smallObject = {"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C","q":"Q"};
const largeObject = {"a":"AA","b":"BB","c":"CC","d":"DD","e":"EE","f":"FF"};

const resultObj = Object.entries(smallObject).reduce((res, [k, v]) =>
  ({...res, [k]: (largeObject[k] === undefined) ? v : largeObject[k]}), {});

console.log(resultObj);
```