# How to validate value of passing object

Tags: javascript, validation, object

So, let's say that i have an object:

```
const object = {
   name: 'Lukas'
}
```

Now i wish to validate this object, so i'm doing this:

```
const validator = {
  name: value => {
    if (!value) return 'No value provided'
  }
}
```

How to pass object to validator to correctly check value?

`validator['name']` returns function
`validator[object]` returns undefined

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You call it with `validator.name(object.name);`

Comment: @LiefdeWen What if i don't know the key?

Comment: Whose key don't you know? The objects?

Comment: @Lukas Renzo's answer is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this `validator['name'](false)` . Because your `name` property type is a `function`.

```js
const validator = {
  name: value => {
    if (!value) return 'No value provided'
    else return "else"
  }
}

console.log(validator['name'](false));
```

Comment: Hey, one question, how to check that there is no provided key/value in object for specific validator? i.e. I have `surname` validator but in object without it?

Comment: `if(validator['surname'])` if this case return `undefined` no provided for `surname`.

Comment: Thanks guys you help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can call it with validator.name(), if you don't know the name of the property you can iterate through the object properties an call on each of them.

```js
    const object = {
           name: 'Lukas',
           lastname: 'Smith'
    }

    const validator = {
      name: value => {
        if (!value) return 'No value provided'
        else return value;
      },
      lastname: value => {
        if (!value) return 'No value provided'
        else return value;
      }
    }



        for(let key in validator)
        {
          if (validator.hasOwnProperty(key) && 
              object.hasOwnProperty(key))
          {
            console.log(validator[key](object[key]))    
          }
        }
```

Correct me If I didn't understood but if you want to validate but if you want to validate calling from your validator you could do it like this..

Comment: Ok, looks nice, but what if i want to validate each key/value in object separately, like:  `name: value => {` / `lastname: value => {`?

Comment: Just one more, how to check that there is no provided value of existing validator?

Comment: Its already beeing checked with this validation object.hasOwnProperty(key)

Comment: Thanks guys you help me a lot!

Comment: You really should drop those `hasOwnProperty` checks - the `validator` one [because it's useless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572) and the `object` one because the validator should still check it when it's `undefined`.

Comment: Actually did this because of that what you've just mentioned.