# Iterate through and access both array and object elements with the same code

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

Let's say I have a function that receives either an object or an array. I would like to iterate through each element, and do something to each element as I go. I know that I can iterate through an array with `forEach()` or a normal for loop. I can also iterate through an object and array with [a for in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-plain-javascript-object-with-objects-as-members). But unlike the array case I have to check the object's elements with `hasOwnProperty()`.

Can I just apply some general piece of code to both arrays and objects?

Update. This is my attempt for some object/array called value, but no console messages appear for the object case:

```
keysArray = Object.keys(value);
for(let key in keysArray) {
    console.log(value[key])
}
```

Comment: You could use `Object.entries`.

Comment: Perhaps [lodash collection methods](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map) are of use to you?

Comment: Show some code that you understand we can take it from there.

Comment: "*I have to check the object's elements with hasOwnProperty()*" - no, [you probably don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45014347/1048572). And no, you [shouldn't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
function* entries(o) {
    if (Array.isArray(o))
        for (let i=0; i<o.length; i++)
            yield [i, o[i]];
    else
        for (const p in o)
            yield [p, o[i]];
}
// or using builtin iterators:
function entries(o) {
    return Array.isArray(o) ? o.entries() : Object.entries(o).values();
}
```

and call it as

```
for (const [key, value] of entries(something)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Of course you can do a similar thing to get just the keys or just the values.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. I'll have to look this up. Does the `*` declare a generator?

Comment: @chamilton Yes, that's a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Answer (score 1):

```
// whatever can be object or array

function doSth(whatever) {
  let myLoopable = whatever;

  // obj to array
  if (!Array.isArray(whatever)) {
    myLoopable = Object
      .keys(whatever) // get array of keys
      .reduce((acc, curKey) => [...acc, whatever[curKey]], []); // get array of values
  }

  myLoopable.forEach(value => console.log(value));
}
```

This is an example, not the best, you must do your own to check if it is object or not to make sure your function not failed

Comment: I think you want `map`, not `reduce`.

Comment: `map` is another choice :D. It's up to you

Comment: Well it would be a great improvement in simplicity, readability and performance…

Comment: for performance, I am sure I have no idea. for simplicity & readability, i am sure it equals. `map` and `reduce` have theirs own meaning and approach. I must agree that most people are not comfortable with `reduce`, but it's not because complexity.

Comment: Yes, they have their own meaning - and when you mean to map the array to a new one, you should not use `reduce`.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give me some references for why "you should not use reduce". Thanks

Comment: I think I already gave you enough reasons. I can't provide more resources, you'll have to believe me.

Comment: wow, you just say by yourself, no number, no chart, no information shows  why "should NOT use `reduce` when mapping an array to a new one", or how fast to use `map` over `reduce`. Ok, if you don't want to share knowledge, ok, fine.

Comment: What chart, what number do you need to judge simplicity and readability? Apply a code metric you believe in. If you want to compare performance, do a benchmark - I don't need to do it for you.

Comment: Have you tried writing a solution with `map`, do you know what it would look like? Please post it. The comparison should be obvious then.

Comment: Ok, end here, you gave a statement, I asked for an evidence. You didn't want to give it. I also don't have time and duty to prove what you said. You even didn't read my question. I've never mention about simplicity and readability in my question.