# Iterating through object list and check property value

Tags: javascript, performance, loops

I have an object list:

```
var myObj = {
   obj1: {name: "bob", employed: true},
   obj2: {name: "dave", employed: false},
   obj3: {name: "james", employed: true},
}
```

What is the most efficient/elegant way to iterate through the object list and count how many objects are equal `employed: true`. Is there a short way to write this? I was thinking of implementing it like below:

```
const countEmployed = () => {
    for (let key in myObj) {
      if (myObj .hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just [drop the `if (myObj .hasOwnProperty(key))` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can use `Object.values()` to get all the property values first. Then you can use `Array.filter()` to get only the necessary ones.

Based on that I would do the following:

```js
const myObj = {
   obj1: {name: "bob", employed: true},
   obj2: {name: "dave", employed: false},
   obj3: {name: "james", employed: true},
}

const result = Object.values(myObj).filter(e => e.employed);
console.log('Count:', result.length);
```

Read further here:

1. [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
2. [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.reduce()` on the `Object.values()` by using the boolean value of `employed` as a number to add to the total like so:

```js
const myObj = {
   obj1: {name: "bob", employed: true},
   obj2: {name: "dave", employed: false},
   obj3: {name: "james", employed: true},
};

const sum = Object.values(myObj).reduce((t, {employed}) => t+employed, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually efficient isn't equal to elegant, however if you are looking for a short and elegant method, you could use `Array#filter`:

```js
const myObj = {
   obj1: {name: "bob", employed: true},
   obj2: {name: "dave", employed: false},
   obj3: {name: "james", employed: true},
};

const r = Object.values(myObj).filter(({ employed }) => employed).length;

console.log(r);
```

**However**, the most efficient way would be probably to use a for in loop and just increase a counter if the `employed` value is truthy.