# Fixing 'The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype'

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach, eslint, for-in-loop

I have this code:

```
data.forEach(item => {
    for (const i in Object.keys(item)) {
      const key = Object.keys(item)[i];
      //..
    }
  });
```

eslint throwing an error:

> error  The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to
> filter unwanted properties from the prototype  guard-for-in

I did research and tried to fix that this way:

```
data.forEach(item => {
if (pattern.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    for (const i in Object.keys(item)) {
      const key = Object.keys(item)[i];
      //..
    }
  }
});
```

So that made the linter happy but the `for..in` loop now does not work.

that is the value of the `item` - `{ 'bla': '42' }`

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Never use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), use [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), or use `.forEach` because that's kind of what it's for (`for ... in` is a legacy construct that does all kinds of things you really don't want). And there is _no_ need to double iterate, the top level iteration already does exactly what you want: `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) { ... }` or `Object.entries(items).forEach(([key, value]) => {... });` and off you go.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans great, it seems more like an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: Oh, no, this is _absolutely_ a comment. No one familiar with iterating over lists would write a double-nested loop on the _same_ list =)

Answer (score 3):

It should be either

```
for (const key of Object.keys(item)) {
  …
}
```

or

```
Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
  …
});
```

or

```
for (const key in item) {
  …
}
```

but not a mix of `for … in` with `Object.keys`. Also no, [it should not be necessary to wrap loop bodies in `if` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572), better disable that linter rule (and rather [enable `no-prototype-builtins`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins), which would've caught your broken fix).