# How to iterate through wikipedias API call where the pages keys are all unique

Tags: javascript, api, wikipedia

Tring to iterate through Wikipedia's API call where the page keys are all unique. Creating a response, to give results that are more akin to being useful. Also working with noodl.net hence the inputs and outputs.

```
let resultPagesArray = Response.content.query.pages;
let resultPagesArrayEntries.entries();

// Loop
let wikiPagesArray = [];

for (let i = 0;i <resultPagesArray.length;i++) {

console.log(i);

    let obj = Noodl.Object.create ( {
        name:i.names,
        url:i.urls,
        imageUrl:i.imageUrls,
        description:i.descriptions
        });
        
    wikiPagesArray.push (obj);
}

Outputs.resultPages = resultPagesArray;
```

Current response:

````
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "continue": {
    "gsroffset": 10,
    "continue": "gsroffset||"
  },
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "454403": {
        "pageid": 454403,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Deep web",
        "index": 3,
        "extract": "The deep web, invisible web, or hidden web are parts of the World Wide Web whose contents are not indexed by standard web search-engines."
      },
      "3422674": {
        "pageid": 3422674,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Form (HTML)",
        "index": 9,
        "extract": "A webform, web form or HTML form on a web page allows a user to enter data that is sent to a server for processing."```
````

Comment: `let resultPagesArrayEntries.entries();` is a syntax error. And `resultPagesArray` is not an array, it's an object: you need to loop it using `for (const pageId in resultPagesArray) { const i = resultPagesArray[pageId]; … }`

Comment: Have an updated still struggling: ```// Input 
let searchPages = Response.content.query.pages;

// Loop
var p = searchPages;
for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        let obj = Noodl.Object.create ({
            id: p.pageid,
            name: p.title,
            url: p.url,
            imageUrl: p.imageUrls,
            description: p.extract
            });
            
        // console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
        wikiPagesArray.push (obj);

    }
}

// Output 
Outputs.resultPages = obj;```

Comment: Use `p[key].pageId`, `p[key].title` and so on, or a helper variable `const page = p[key]`. Also [don't use `p.hasOwnProperty(key)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572).