# error The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype guard-for-in

Tags: javascript, eslint

Im getting error in following command, it doesn't allow me to commit to git

```
toJSON: function () 
{
    let json = _.clone(this.attributes);

    // add in the calclueted fields for evnt model
    if (typeof this.calFields === 'object') {
        // eslint-disable-line guard-for-in
        for (var comp in this.calFields) {
            var v2;
            if (this._computedCache && this._computedCache[comp]) {
                v2 = this._computedCache[comp];
            }
            else {
                v2 = this.calFields[comp].apply(this);
            }
            json[comp] = v2;
        }
    }
    return json;
}
```

giving following error

> error  The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to
> filter unwanted properties from the prototype  guard-for-in

Comment: [This advice is largely outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45014347/1048572). Disable the rule in your linter settings.

Comment: [`eslint-disable-line` goes on the same line as the problematic code](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#disabling-rules). You want `eslint-disable-next-line`

Comment: "eslint-disable-next-line" this works, can you summarise add as an answer im happy to accept ?