# Finding value of javascript object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi really new to javascript and am hoping to get some help with a problem im facing.

So I basically have an array that stores objects. Each object contains an id and a variable i which is a number. My question is this: how can I extract the value of i from the object array with the id value? The id that I am using would already have been stored in the array with an i value.

```
var i = 1;
var id;
var b = {}; 
var y = [];

if(condition) {

  b = {"123":i};

  y.push(b);

}

if(condition) {
  id = 123;
  //Find corresponding i value for id "123" from object array y
  i = ?;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: The suggested solutions are for jQuery. Will they work for javascript too? @JaredSmith

Comment: [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is not jQuery. I actually don't see any jQuery solutions suggested (yet). And remember, jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

An example with [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var hasOwn = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);
var i = 1;
var id;
var b = {};
var y = [];

var condition = true;
if (condition) {
  b = {
    "123": i
  };

  y.push(b);
}

if (condition) {
  id = 123;
  // Find corresponding i value for id "123" from object array y
  // i = ? ;
  var found = y.find(function(o) {
    return hasOwn(o, id);
  });
  var f = found ? found[id] : found;
  console.log(f);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/es7-shim@latest"></script>
```

Comment: While this answer does find the value of "i", the items array doesn't match the example that was given by the OP.

Comment: No, because this was posted before the Q was edited. :)

Comment: There can be issues with calling "hasOwnProperty" in some browsers.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157700/object-has-no-hasownproperty-method-i-e-its-undefined-ie8

Comment: Like I care about IE8. :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use  `ObjectName[Key]` this is enoughto get you the value 
Like `b[123]`

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this. Here is one of them.

```js
var arr = [{id:1},{id:123}];

var obj = arr.filter(function(val){
   if(val.id===123)
  return val

})

console.log(obj,'obj')
```

Comment: the output i get for this is [] 'obj'. Any idea why?

Comment: @user3702643 have you run the snippet.

Comment: I ran it on my local environment. Cant seem to get the same result.

Comment: [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will always give you an array, and it may contain 0 or 1 or more elements. It's probably not the best choice in this use case.

Comment: @Xotic750 correct. but we dont know if the ID is duplicate.

Comment: Find all matching wasn't hinted at, hence I say probably. :)

Comment: @Xotic750c actually he need just `i` value. So it will have only one value.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and get the object property value as follows:

```js
var arr = [
    {"123": "valueA"},
    {"456": "valueB"}
];

const id = "123";
let value;

arr.some(obj => {
    if (obj[id] || obj[id] === 0) value = obj[id];
});

console.log(value);
```

[Documentation for "Array.some" method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: It would be better to use [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) than [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: What if the value for `i` was `0`?

Comment: The correct value for "0" should be returned - now that I've updated the answer. :)

Comment: The keywords `const` and `let`, and `Arrow functions` can cause an issue in some browsers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
const stuff = [
  {
    name: 'Leonardo',
    id: 100
  },
  {
    name: 'Donatello',
    id: 101
  },
  {
    name: 'Raphael',
    id: 102
  },
  {
    name: 'Michaelangelo',
    id: 103
  },
];
```

First, use the `Array.prototype.find()` method on the array to find the object within it that has the desired ID and store it in the `entry` variable. Then, log the value corresponding to the `name` key within that object.

```
const desired = 102;
const entry = stuff.find(item => item.id === desired);

console.log(entry.name);
```