# Terminology for different types of functions

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, terminology

There seem to be several different "groups" of function-like things in JavaScript. Here are my made-up names for them:

- "Regular functions": These are callable with parens and with `new`. Most functions fall into this category.
- "Constructor-only functions": These are callable with `new` only. For example, `Image`, `DOMParser`, etc.
- "Non-constructor functions": These are callable with parens, but not with `new`. For example, `Math.round`, `Function.prototype`.
- "Non-callable functions": These functions aren't callable at all. For example, `window.constructor`, `Document`, `NodeList`, etc.

What are the proper names for these different groups of functions?

---

I'm also trying to figure out if which "group" a function is in can be determined based on whether its `[[Prototype]]` (`__proto__`) property is set to `Function.prototype`.

- Most "regular functions" will have `Function.prototype`, but it could be removed using non-standard `__proto__`.
- Most "constructor-only functions" have `Object.prototype`. I can't find any cases where they have `Function.prototype` (so, no `call` or `apply`). Is this always the case / spec'd behavior?
- "Non-constructor functions" seem to mostly have `Function.prototype` with the exception of `Function.prototype` itself. Are there other cases which have `Object.prototype`?
- "Non-callable functions" seem to always have `Object.prototype`. Is that the case?

---

I'll respond to some answers here:

> Regular function: `function`
>   Constructor: `constructor`
>   Non-constructor: `method`
>   Non-callable: `interface`

This isn't really what I'm looking for. "function" and "constructor" are of course correct in a general way, but I'm looking for something more specific ("non-constructor function", etc.).

"method" is no better than "function" in telling you it can't be called with `new`, and `constructor` doesn't get the point across that it can *only* be called with `new`.

In many cases, the non-callable functions are only accessible from the `constructor` property of a host object. I think *most* of these would more accurately be called "constructors" than "interfaces."

---

> [Stuff about host objects vs native objects]

This is sort of on the right track. Taking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects) (and the accepted answer, and its comments) into consideration, there seems to be some disagreement or confusion about whether user-defined functions are host or native objects.

To avoid that, let's just call user-defined functions UDFs, and not worry about whether they are host or native. So we have UDFs, host objects, and native objects.

- "Regular functions"

  - Every UDF
  - Native objects like `Object`, `String`, etc.
  - Host objects like `window.toString` (tested in Chrome 18).
- "Constructor-only functions"

  - No native objects?
  - Host objects like `DOMParser`, `Image`.
- "Non-constructor functions"

  - Native objects like `Math.round` and `Function.prototype`.
  - Host objects like `DOMParser#parseFromString`.
- "Non-callable functions"

  - No native objects?
  - Host objects like `NodeList`, `DocumentFragment`.

So it looks like there could be a connection between host objects and constructor-only / non-callable functions, but host vs native doesn't seem to apply to non-constructor and regular functions.

Comment: You and your terminology questions again! :)

Comment: Heh, it's been bothering me for days this time. I wonder if I'm just making up artificial categories where there are none, but I want to call it *something*.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) is a good introduction to object-oriented JavaScript, which should answer your question.

Comment: @sp00m it doesn't answer it at all. I guess this question is confusing, I will try to think of a way to reword it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are picking up on here is the nuances between native objects built in to EcmaScript and host objects, ones created and supplied by the developer.

The "Regular Functions" map to Host Objects, that is to say functions created using JS and "Constructor-only functions",Non-constructor functions" and "Non-callable functions" map to native objects built into the language at a lower level.

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an official naming for what you're asking, but usually this is how people call all those functions in any programming language:

- Regular function: `function`
- Constructor: `constructor`
- Non-constructor: `method`
- Non-callable: `interface` (in the case of JS, this refers to native objects at a lower level)