# Why in Firefox Function.prototype.func=... doesn't affect console.log?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have added a function using `Function.prototype.func = ...` to `Function` but in Firefox it has not been added `console.log`:

```
Function.prototype.func = function () { return this.toString(); };
alert(typeof console.log.func); // in FF: undefined, in Chrome: function
```

Is it a bug or is there any reason for that?

Comment: Perhaps it's because `console` is a *host object*, which means it is not bound by specification rules -- see [What is the difference between native objects and host objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects)

Comment: @apsillers thanks, I'm trying other host objects, but it seems they don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite telling that in Firefox:

```
var foo = function() {}
foo.__proto__ == Function.prototype;
```

is `true`, whereas the statements:

```
console.log.__proto__ == Function.prototype;
console.log instanceof Function;
```

are both `false`.

Thus, `console.log` does not include `Function.prototype` in its prototype chain, so altering `Function.prototype` has no affect on `console.log`. This is perfectly fine, since `console` is a [host object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects) (rather than a native object in the ECMAScript specification) and may behave however Mozilla (or Google, or Microsoft, etc.) would like.

*Why* does this behavior exist? I'm not a Firefox dev, so I can't say for certain, but my best guess is that this was done specifically because `console` is a *debugging tool*. If you muck around with `Function`'s prototype chain and then want to use `console.log` to verify what you're doing, it would be terrible if your debug reporting tool *itself* starting messing up and misreporting things to you.

**EDIT:**

The `console` functions have a separate prototype chain used by all of them:

```
console.log.__proto__ == console.dir.__proto__ // true
console.log.__proto__.func = 5;
console.dir.__proto__.func == 5  // true
```

Comment: hum, maybe that's the reason. btw, `console` is a host object but `console.log` is a function which I guess is not a host object.

Comment: it's just curious that `typeof console.log` returns 'function', and `console.log.constructor` returns "Function()" and `console.log.constructor.name` returns "Function" yet it is not affected by `prototype`

Comment: @CrayonViolent that's why i'm really confused.

Comment: I think apsillers' theory about *why* is plausible though. IOW it is a host object designed to look and feel like a native object for the purposes of testing that it exists, but it doesn't allow you to prototype it to keep you from messing with it

Comment: @CrayonViolent Yes, `Function.prototype` and `console.log.__proto__` are both anonymous functions, but they're not the *same* anonymous function. In fact, in FF, *all* `console` functions (`dir`/`log`/`err`/`warn`) share the same anonymous function as their parent prototype, but it's not the same anonymous function used for `Function.prototype`.

Comment: FYI Firefox's console API is defined in https://github.com/mozilla-services/services-central-legacy/blob/master/dom/base/ConsoleAPI.js

Comment: @apsillers The main reason that console.log does not have Function.prototype on the proto chain is that it's not a function at all.  It's a callable proxy that enforces certain security restrictions before forwarding the call to the actual function.  And no one bothered to make sure that when proxying a function the security membranes use Function.prototype as their prototype....