# IE8 querySelector null vs normal null

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I just found really interesting behaviour in ie8. It turns out null is not always null.

```js
// just normal, casual null hanging out in the sun
var nullA = null;
// query for non existing element, should get null, same behaviour also for getElementById
var nullB = document.querySelector('asdfasfdf');

// they are equal
console.log(nullA === nullB);

// false
nullA instanceof Object;

// will throw 'Object expected' error in ie8. Black magic
nullB instanceof Object;
```

Anyone has an explanation for that?

Comment: it looks like a host object (host objects are not bound to behave in any way) that pretends to be a null.

Comment: I could not reproduce that behavior. Win7 / IE10 / IE8 browser mode / IE8 document mode / blank page. Do I need a real IE8?

Comment: I only observe the correct behavior. Is this the full test case you're using? Include the logging calls, please

Comment: Yes, real IE8 is needed.

Comment: This is the full code that will throw error in real IE8 browser. I just tested it under ie10 in ie8 mode and I get the correct behavior.

Comment: @MartinVelinsky: I just tested this in real IE 8 (Windows XP running in a VM), and I do, in fact, get `Object expected`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, Jan Dvorak is definitely right.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects), `null` is a native object and `querySelector` is a host object.

Host object behavior is not well defined in the [ECMA specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.8), so its behavior is up to the implementation, and IE8 and IE10 have different JScript implementations, which is why, even in "IE8 Mode" the JavaScript engine in IE10 processes the objects differently (and better). It does appear that this particular host object in this particular implementation would be in violation of Sec 4.3.8 requiring it's `prototype` to be `null` or `Object` as it appears not to have inherited its `instanceOf` value.

It appears to be a bug in IE8 implementation of JScript (!== ECMAScript || JavaScript) that was fixed when they switched to the [Chakra engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JScript_engine)).

All that being said, if it hurts when you do that, don't do that. Just check to see if `document.querySelector() === null`.

Hope that sheds some light on it. For more info, see the linked answer, they did a great job explaining.