# How to include a classic asp written in Javascript from another classic asp file also written in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am working on a classic ASP project and unfortunately cannot switch to another technology. I learned that it's possible to write server side classic ASP code in Javascript (ES3) so I did some investigation but I cannot find a way to include another JS based ASP file from my JS based ASP file.

Here is the JS based ASP file I want to import:

**includejs.asp**

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript %>

<%
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 + p2;
}

%>
```

And I tried the following 2 ways, neither worked

**myjs1.asp**

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript %>

<script language="JScript" runat="server" src="./includejs.asp"></script>

<%
    // myFunction is from another file
    Response.Write(myFunction(20,2));
%>
```

**myjs2.asp**

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript %>

<!--#include virtual="./includejs.asp" -->

<%
    // myFunction is from another file
    Response.Write(myFunction(20,2));
%>
```

**My findings**

I was able to import a pure javascript file like the following with my first attempt

```
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 + p2;
}
```

but I want to include a ASP wrapped javascript so that I can include other files from the included Js file too.

Comment: `#include` syntax is IIS Server Side Includes, you should be able to use it fine with JScript. Just wrap include file `includejs.asp` in a `<script lamguage="JScript">` or place `<%@ Language="JScript" %>` at the top of the include file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I updated my question to include what I tried @Lankymart

Comment: Notice that Lankymart said `<script lamguage="JScript">`   it is JScript, not JavaScript

Comment: Remove the `<@ Language=` line from the include file, as it will result in multiple page directives in the including file.

Comment: Tbh @Dijkgraaf, I think the `language` attribute accepts both but treats them both as [tag:JScript].

Comment: Also, this might be useful - [What are the functional differences between JScript, JavaScript, and ECMA Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18793640)

Comment: @Flakes good catch, I did hint at this in my comment but not as clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Thanks for @Flakes's comment about I shouldn't put <%@ Language=JavaScript %> again in the include file, which was exactly the reason why my second approach above didn't work.

Here I put a more complicated working example just in case anyone needs it.

myjs.asp includes lib.asp which includes lib2.asp

**myjs.asp** - lib2() function is from lib2.asp which is included by lib.asp

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript %>

<!--#include file="lib.asp" -->

<%
    Response.Write(lib());
    Response.Write(lib2());
%>
```

**lib.asp**

```
<!--#include file="lib2.asp" -->

<%
function lib() {
    return "this is lib.asp";
}
%>
```

**lib2.asp**

```
<%
function lib2() {
    return "this is lib2.asp";
}

function myFunction2(p1, p2) {
    return p1 * p2;
}
%>
```

Many things can go wrong, so you have to be careful in every detail.

One thing to note is that if you are using relative path like I do and your lib.asp is in the same directory, you have to use **file=...** instead of **virtual=...** during #include statement. Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp) to see more details about file vs. virtual in include directive