# When is a javascript function not an object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm seeing the following behaviour, in the middle of a javascript debug session:

```
o // function (a1, a2, a3) {  return a1 + a2 + a3; }

typeof(o) //'function'

for (var n in o) { console.log(n); } //<a list of properties>

Object.keys(o) //TypeError: not an object

Object.prototype.toString.call(o); //"[object Function]"
```

which makes me wonder - can a function, ever not be object?

[running on Chrome 29, on a mac]

---

Note that this is in the middle of a very complex debug session. I don't exactly know where 'o' is coming from, or how it was created. Also, I've so far been unable to reproduce this issue with a simple test case. A simple setup works as expected:

```
var t = function() { return true; } //undefined
t.a = "aa" //"aa"
Object.keys(t) //["a"]
```

Comment: Please reconstruct where `o` was coming from - maybe it is a buggy host object. The question is useless however if this is not reproducable.

Comment: I get an empty array when I try that on a function with no properties (also in Chrome 29/Mac). Functions are *always* objects.

Comment: No error,chrome 29.0.1547.66 m on win7.

Comment: You were not using a ES5 shim that overwrites `Object.keys` despite its existence and that does the type check wrong (with `typeof`)?

Comment: I'm not looking for debugging help - I'm looking to better understand javascript. Clearly, sometimes, functions are not objects - either this is correct behaviour, or I've run into something much funkier (ie, a virtual machine bug or equivalent)

Comment: @Bergi the question is not useless if not reproducible.  The asker is asking in general terms, meaning that someone who understands JavaScript well enough should be able to answer the question without needing to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: *"Clearly, sometimes, functions are not objects..."* No that's the part that's not clear without a reproduceable test

Comment: @blueberryfields: Your problem reminds me of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721969/ie8-queryselector-null-vs-normal-null.  The issue is (probably) that `0` is a "host object", which makes up its own rules.

Comment: Instead of `typeof o`, try `Object.prototype.toString.call(o);`

Comment: Alright, now try `o + ""` to see what you get.

Comment: "function (a1, a2, a3) {
    return a1 + a2 + a3;
  }"

Comment: When you say you don't know where `o` comes from or how it was created, are you saying it's not in your code at all, but appears in the debugger?

Comment: Is there any asynchronous code running? Can you post a larger sample of your actual code?

Comment: "o" is an object that appears in the system I'm debugging. i can see it's source (it's not much more complex than i document it to be). i don't see any asynchronous code working anywhere, but the system is large, maybe i'm missing something? when i attempt to reproduce this by just copying the code i'm looking at, and manually creating o from its source code, i don't see the error message... still, how would an async system cause this kind of problem?

Comment: Does this only occur when you're stepping through code in the debugger? Or does it always happen? The async code would need to be in between (or part of) the lines of code you show at the top, and would need to have an effect on the `o` variable.

Comment: if `for (var n in o) { console.log(n); }` gives you a list of properties, that would be odd since the properties of a function are non-enumerable. What are the properties it gives?

Comment: ahahahaha. It's a custom implementation of  "Object.keys"! I'm going to go smack my head into some bricks.

Comment: @blueberryfields: If I may ask, how is it that you didn't know you had a broken `Object.keys()` overwriting the native one? Could you post the source in an answer?

Comment: @Bergi deserves credit for [anticipating an overwrite of `Object.keys`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857500/when-is-a-function-not-an-object/18857728?noredirect=1#comment27825254_18857500) a long time ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see something like this, you might try:

```
console.log(Object.keys)
```

or equivalent.

(if you can find the original implementation of keys for your browser, to compare and make sure it's identical to what you're seeing)

(read the comments on the question for more ideas of things to look at if seeing this kind of problem)

---

False alarm. Functions are always objects, and the people at Chrome know how to make virtual machines.

I ran

```
grep -r "Object.defineProperty(" *

grep -r "Object.defineProperties(" *
```

and found a place where Object.keys is being overwritten, with a buggy function.

The related code was being loaded dynamically, so I didn't get to see it explicitly get loaded in the browser.

Comment: Good job. I suggest you leave this question with all the answers/comments. There is a lot of interesting knowledge here.

Comment: Whatever code you have that dynamically loaded a broken overwrite of `Object.keys` needs to be removed from your code base, followed by an email to the developer suggesting that they apply for a job at their local car wash..

Comment: @user2736012 it's on my todo list... One thing at a time :P

Comment: ...but +1 for drilling down to the issue. In retrospect, a `console.log(Object.keys)` would have been a good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The first step performed by the `Object.keys` [algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) is:

> 1. If the Type(*O*) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.

Since you're getting such an error, I believe your object must be a *host* object, as Bergi [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857500/when-is-a-function-not-an-object#comment27825201_18857500) above. Still, it's strange that `Object.prototype.toString.call(o)` is giving "[object Function]", since [host objects are not allowed to use "Function" as their `[[Class]]` property value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2).

<sup>* For the meaning of `Type(x)`, see the last sentence from [Section 8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8) of the spec.</sup>

Comment: See also, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721969/ie8-queryselector-null-vs-normal-null

Comment: @user2736012 I'm not saying it can't work on a host object (it does work on document and window in Chrome, for example). And my first version was incorrect, the spec says the type must be Object, or an error will be thrown.

Comment: Deleting my comment because you updated. But looking at the `Object.prototype.toString.call` output, it seems to be native, unless there's a bug. The output `[object Function]` isn't permitted for host objects.

Comment: @user2736012 That's actually not true: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2

Comment: @bfavaretto Specification actually defines host/native objects. What worries me is that there is no such distinction in that condition, i.e. you can't assume that by `Object` they mean native object. Besides, I can't see an example of `Object.keys` not working with a host object.

Comment: @freakish No, because 15.2.4.2 step 4 uses `[[Class]]`, but section [8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) says: `The value of the [[Class]] internal property of a host object may be any String value except one of "Arguments", "Array", "Boolean", "Date", "Error", "Function", "JSON", "Math", "Number", "Object", "RegExp", and "String"`. Thus, shouldn't `[object Function]` be not spec-compliant for a host object?

Comment: Yep, what @apsillers said.

Comment: @apsillers Fair enough. +1: nice finding.

Comment: @freakish They do mean native Object, see section 8. And user2736012 is right, a host object cannot return `[object Function]` for toString (see [8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2))

Comment: @bfavaretto Could you show me where exactly this is stated? I can't find it.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Could you point out where it states that `Object` can not mean "host object"? I don't see how the last sentence of `8` restricts to native objects.

Comment: @bfavaretto There's even more: every time they talk about host/native object it is clearly stated so, for example: [assume O is a native ECMAScript object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12). And here they even distinguish the same condition: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.2.1 I'm sorry, but this is an overinterpretation of ECMAScript and I have to give -1.

Comment: @freakish My comment was wrong, that's not stated in the spec. In fact, my answer even says that it seems to work with anything that inherits from `Object.prototype`. I'm assuming the object in the OP code doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't even need to inherit from `Object.prototype`. This will work: `Object.keys(Object.create(null));`

Comment: @user2736012 True. I'll stop guessing and delete this answer, since the OP now states he was using a custom Object.keys.

Comment: @bfavaretto Please, don't. There's a lot of knowledge here that might be helpful to someone.