# Understanding Number functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was reading about JavaScript `Number` object on Mozilla Developer Network. I am new to this. Below is my script:

```
var number = 16;
console.log( Number.prototype.toExponential(number) );
console.log( Number.prototype.toFixed(number) );
console.log( Number.prototype.toPrecision(number) );
// DON'T UNDERSTAND WHAT THIS DOES
// console.log( Number.prototype.toSource(number) );
console.log( Number.prototype.valueOf(number) );
```

and the output:

```
0.0000000000000000e+0 
0.0000000000000000 
0.000000000000000 
0
```

I am wondering why I am getting all zeros despite `number = 16`. **Please help me in understanding this.** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have:

```
var number = 16;
console.log(number.toExponential());
console.log(number.toFixed());
console.log(number.toPrecision());
```

*With prototype you can define you own methods and properties of objects*

*With prototype basically extending objects*

Here is a simple example of prototype:

```
Number.prototype.isPrime = function() {
    if ( this === 0 || this === 1 ) {
        return false;
    }
    for ( var i = 2; i < this; i++ ) {
        if ( this % i === 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

var arr = [2,4,5,13,15,121];

for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(arr[i].isPrime());
}
```

In this example `this` keyword refers to number object (so you don't have to pass any argument in function for manipulation)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mnv3a/)

Take a look on [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: But please never change Host objects in real life.

Comment: Well now I am having a hard time deciding whose answer to accept. xD

Comment: @phylax What does that mean ? :)

Comment: Host objects are `Number`, `Array`, `String` ... changing their behaviour is considered bad practice. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223449/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-modify-javascript-objects-prototypes

Comment: @phylax: Those aren't Host objects, and in real life it can be useful to extend their prototypes. Different people have different *opinions* on the matter, but there's nothing inherently wrong with it. It's more situational.

Comment: *looks bewildered.* I just asked for help with my `Number` functions. Did I just start a JavaScript war ? LOL #justKidding

Comment: @phylax Like cookie monster said I don't see any problem in this, anyways I just showed an example how `prototype` works

Comment: Ok, didn't wanted to start ar war here. More about host objects and native objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects - of course there is no law which forbits it but not to mess with those objects is a rule wich i took from people knowing much more about JavaScript then me and to me it was a good rule.

Comment: @phylax The way you are talking `prototype` is not good practice not only `Host` objects but also in user defined functions, because `methods` can be defined inside a `function` not outside of it as during initialization firstly invoked inside defined ones

Comment: @phylax: There will always be people who adopt a certain set of coding conventions and then go around telling people that they are "best practices" and deviation from them are "bad practice". In reality, the true "best practice" is to fully understand the ramifications of *any* approach to programming and to decide what to do in a given situation based on that understanding.

Comment: ...if we can never change native or host prototypes, then we could never polyfill missing methods. That would be a terribly unfortunate  consequence of applying made-up rules in an unnecessarily broad manner. Even jQuery modifies host objects to implement its `jQuery.cache`.

Comment: @ToKeN i dont fully understand what you are trying to say. You say its ok to modify prototype of objects i havent implemented by my self because those objects could modify their own prototypes during runtime? That sounds like an argument not to do it.

Comment: @cookiemonster i allways readjust my conventions by things i read and compare to things others have written. I just searched 'javascript host objects prototype' and found more then one article about it, explaining why its bad. I'm still reading. And by the way, there was no article saying its good.

Comment: @phylax The only `bad` thing about it could be that through the iteration of objects there will be the name of extended function by prototype which can easily solved with `hasOwnProperty`, anyways do your best as you think it is good for you

Comment: @phylax: That's because people are far more likely to write about things they perceive to be bad, rather than things that are neutral. It's never good to take a solution to a single situation where something can have an ill effect and apply it to all situations. Again, a good developer will understand the ramifications of every approach to coding, and make decisions on a case by case basis.

Comment: ...and jQuery's "plugin" system is entirely based on extending a `.prototype` of a constructor that the end developer didn't implement.

Comment: Anyhow, i want to state one last thing which could have been misunderstood. Im *not* saying modifying prototype is a bad thing in general. I'm talking about host objects and native objects. jQuery is explicitly meant to be extended this way and does not apply to this toppic.

Comment: @phylax: Any problem encountered by modifying a native, host or any other prototype can be equally encountered by modifying jQuery's prototype. There's no difference. There's nothing special about jQuery's constructor that would make it any different from any other. Every mutable `.prototype` is explicitly meant to be extended if one chooses to do so. The same considerations need to be made in all cases. Your distinction is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

Number.prototype functions live on actual numbers (the prototype is the definition for a specific type. String variables have functions that live on String.prototype, arrays have functions defined on Array.prototype, etc. http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html is a good starting place to learn about prototype inheritance), so just call `number.toFixed()`, `number.toFixed()` etc. You can even do `(16).toString()` etc.

You're calling the function "on nothing" by calling the prototype function, instead of "on 16".

Comment: Please explain the `.prototype` concept to me :) I have never seen it before :)

Comment: it's the entire underpinning of object oriented javascript... =) Objects have types that are defined by a prototype, and instances share all prototype functions. You definitely want to read up on it with something like "JavaScript: the good parts" to familiarise yourself with the very core of how JavaScript works =)

Comment: So far what I have learned has been how to use JavaScript rather than the workings. Like I said, I am new to this. Any good book you recommend ? :)

Comment: I updated the answer with a useful link for you, the rest of Crockford's writing on JavaScript is generally worth reading, too, if you're learning JavaScript

Comment: @LittleChild Take a look at my example

Comment: @LittleChild: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Answer (score 2):

You will have better luck if you do the following:

```
var number = new Number(16);
console.log(number.toExponential());
console.log(number.toFixed());
console.log(number.toPrecision());
console.log(number.valueOf());
```

*Note* It's preferable not to use numbers in javascript this way unless you have a specific need to avoid primitives.*

The reason you are getting 0 is because the Number prototype defaults to zero if it is not instantiated.

**Number** is a prototype which is designed semantically to be used to spawn new objects which inherit these methods.  These methods are not designed to be called directly from the **Number** prototype, but instead from the numbers themselves.  Try the following:

```
(16).toExponential();
```

*You have to wrap the number in parenthesis so the interpreter knows you're accessing methods and not defining a floating point.*

The important thing here to understand is that the **Number prototype provides all the methods that all numbers will inherit in javascript.**

To explain further why you are getting a 0, the methods on the Number prototype are intended to be "bound" to a number object.  They will use the bound object for input and will ignore any arguments.  Since they are bound to the default Number object, the default number is 0, and therefore all methods will return their version of 0.

There is a way in javascript to rebind methods to an object using the "call" method (there's also bind and apply):

```
Number.prototype.toExponential.call(16);
```

Comment: You should not advocate the use of `new Number`. Some less experience dev might pick that up and run into all sorts of problems later on. I like the rest of the answer though :)

Comment: I'm merely using it to demonstrate how the Number prototype is instantiated.  Of course, I also provide the "primitive" way of accessing the associated methods.

Comment: However, if I may ask, why is the use of `new Number` frowned upon?

Comment: Mainly because it makes comparison inconsistent. E.g. `new Number(16) === new Number(16)` is `false`. `new Number(0) < new Number(16)` is `true`. Sideeffects of working with an object instead of a primitive value.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var number = 16;
console.log( Number.prototype.toExponential.call(number) );
```

Notice the `call()` which calles the method `toExponential` of the `Number` object on an instance.