# Check Prime Number In PHP

Tags: php

My html document has the following form:

```
<form action="PrimeNumber.php" method="post">
Enter a number to determine if it is a prime number: <input type="text" name="numb" size="10">
<input type="submit" value="Check for Primeness">
</form>
```

Edit: Using a different code now but can't get it to echo a statement no matter what I do. Anyone know how I can make it echo is a prime number or is not.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['numb'])) {
        $num = $_POST['numb'];

        function isPrime($num) {
            if($num == 1) {
                return false;
            }

            if($num == 2) {
                return true;
            }

            if($num % 2 == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            for($i = 3; $i <= ceil(sqrt($num)); $i = $i + 2) {
                if($num % $i == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: available on `(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)` is it your case?

Comment: You have to install the GMP package.

Comment: If I install the package will it still work for people viewing it who don't have the package? Thanks BTW.

Comment: Of course it will, it's server-side.

Comment: I don't know what is your issue, though if you are eager to check if number is prime or not here is the algorithm written in `JavaScript` though probably you find it interesting. [Check Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045746/understanding-number-functions-in-javascript/23045785#23045785)

Comment: But even after you install the package are you sure that you will get the desired result with the above code? You need to review your code.

Answer (score 1):

simple and easy to understand code, and working as well. do little changes according to your requirement, like assign input text value to $a variable and you good to go.

```
$a = 51;
for($i=2; $i < $a; $i++){
    if($a % $i == 0){
        echo "Numberis not prime.";
        break;
    }
    else{
        echo "Number is not prime.";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple function to check is prime number:

```
function is_prime($p) {
    return ($p > 1) &&  (($p%2 >= 1) && ($p%3 >= 1) && ($p%5 >= 1)) ||  in_array($p, [2,3,5]);
}
```

Comment: This is NOT correct at all. It returns true for 49 (7*7), 77 (7*11), 121 (11*11) and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkPrime($num){
      $isPrime = true;
    
    for($i = 2; $i <= sqrt($num); $i++)
    {
        if($num % $i == 0) 
        {
          $isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if($isPrime == true)
    {
        return "$num is prime number";
    }else{
        return "$num  is not prime number";
    }
}

echo checkPrime(29);
```

The output is

```
29 is prime number
```

[For More Details](http://www.learnwebtech.in/check-prime-number/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the gmp package and correct your code because I got an output as 11 not being a prime number or use the following function as an alternative.

```
function isPrime($num) {
    if($num == 1) {
        return false;
    }

    if($num == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    if($num % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for($i = 3; $i <= ceil(sqrt($num)); $i = $i + 2) {

        if($num % $i == 0)

            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

More information is available at the following [page](http://icdif.com/computing/2011/09/15/check-number-prime-number/).

Comment: I tried using that, but when I add echo statements after the return of true or false, it doesn't display anything. echo $num.'is a prime number';

Comment: You need to use it in a if-conditional.

Comment: Could you give me a sample because nothing I'm trying is working.

Comment: For eg: `if (isPrime(11)) { echo "PRIME";} else { echo "NO";}`

Comment: if (isPrime($num) == false){
  echo 'Not Prime';
  } //This doesn't work?

Comment: The code does work without any problem... Check it out at this [link](http://codepad.org/GwfxeAum)...

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to help you find out if a number is a prime number

```
<?php 
     function fn_prime($number) {
        $i = 2; $result = TRUE;
        while($i < $number) {
            if(!($number%$i)) {
                $result = FALSE;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $result;
     }
?>
```