# Javascript: Where getter/setter values are stored?

Tags: javascript

Consider the classic getter/setter implementation:

```
var test_obj={
   get num(){return this._size},
   set num(val){this._size=val;}
};
var obj1=Object.create(test_obj);
var obj2=Object.create(test_obj);
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1); //[]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2); //[]
obj1.num=5;
obj2.num=7;
console.log(test_obj.num);  //undefined
console.log(obj1.num);  //5
console.log(obj2.num);  //7
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1); //["_size"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2); //["_size"]
```

The above is completely comprehensible to me since, for example, the value of getter `obj1.num` is stored in *data* property `obj1._size` and the value of getter `obj2.num` is stored in *data* property `obj2._size` (for both objects `obj1` and `obj2`, `_size` is an own property).

**My problem** is I cannot find the equivalent for *built-in getter/setter properties*. There are plenty of them, let's pick **id** which is a getter/setter of **Element.prototype**.

```
var elem=document.getElementById('mydiv');
```

`elem` is an instance object of `HTMLDivElement` interface object, the prototype chain of `elem` includes  `Element.prototype` and now we have:

```
elem.id; //"mydiv"
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(elem); //[]
```

**Where** `elem.id`'s value **is stored** since `elem` does not have any own properties? In our example, it is `_size` that does this job. Maybe, there are some hidden properties upon `elem` which are not accessible? However, I cannot find any way in Javascript to hide an object property.

Thank you

Comment: `elem` is a host object. Which means the implementation can do whatever it wants. In this case, the id is stored in the underlying DOM object (the real one, not just the JS proxy)

Comment: Could you, please, be more analytical, provide more details?

Comment: Not really. In general, when it comes to the DOM, you're leaving the realms of JavaScript, and getting into implementation-specific techniques. It's not a "javascript way" that hides the property - because it's stored in a non-javascript object.

Comment: I think the duplicate answers your question well. See also [What is the difference between native objects and host objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7614317/1048572) for what I meant

Comment: Ok, something last: elem does not point to the real DOM object? What is a JS proxy? Thank you very much.

Comment: `elem` is some kind of js object (accessible from JS) which proxies property accesses to the underlying "real" DOM object (typically implemented in C++ or something).