# What is the difference between Built-in object, Native object and Host object?

Tags: javascript, object, native, host, built-in

A JavaScript object is divided into Native object, and Host object

> Built-in Object : An object that is part of the JavaScript language
>   defined in the ECMAScript specification.
> ex) Global, String,
>   Boolean, Number, Math, RegExp, Object, Function, Array, Date, Math,
>   RegExp, Error
>
> Host Object: Objects built from browsers, those who run the
>   JavaScript engine
> ex) window, document, location, history,
>   XMLHttpRequest, setTimeout, getElementsByTagName, querySelectorAll

and some by Built-in object, Native object, and Host object.

> Built-in Object : An object that is part of the JavaScript language
>   defined in the ECMAScript specification.
> ex) Global, String,
>   Boolean, Number, Math, RegExp, Object, Function, Array, Date, Math,
>   RegExp, Error
>
> Native Object : Objects built from browsers, those who run the
>   JavaScript engine
> ex) window, document, location, history,
>   XMLHttpRequest, setTimeout, getElementsByTagName, querySelectorAll
>
> Host Object : Objects created by the user

Are both correct?
Is it the latter case if I split the host object smaller?

Comment: Where are the two quotes taken from ? They are loosely defined terms but usually Host Objects are associated with what the first definition describes.

Comment: thanks!
I was confused because the description on each site was slightly different.

https://poiemaweb.com/js-built-in-object (is in Korean)

http://insanehong.kr/post/javascript-object/ (is in Korean)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects

Comment: Ok, I'd trust the definition in the specification: http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.6

Comment: There is also a possibility that the JavaScript engine is hosted in a custom environment, which provides its own custom native objects (neither DOM nor Node).

Comment: ah-ha I got it
! thank you :D

Comment: The second quote is wrong.